# Does a finally block always get executed in Java?

Tags: java, error-handling, return, try-catch-finally

Considering this code, can I be *absolutely sure* that the `finally` block always executes, no matter what `something()` is?

```
try {  
    something();  
    return success;  
}  
catch (Exception e) {   
    return failure;  
}  
finally {  
    System.out.println("I don't know if this will get printed out");
}
```

Comment: [Not *always*](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/My-Tales.aspx)

Comment: Effective java says otherwise http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=7

Comment: @BinoyBabu, _finalizer_ != `finally`; _finalizer_ == the `finalize()` method.

Comment: @Boann Correct, "not always" indeed. But then you can *never ever* use the words "guaranteed" or "always".

Comment: @Boann I would put it this way: the execution flow always goes through finally before it escapes the try-finally structure. If it dies inside then I'm fine with that, because the primary purpose of finally is to make sure things are not messed up for other parts of the code.

Comment: Looks like you caught quite a fish there!

Comment: If the `finally` block returns a value, then the try/catch block can't return.

Comment: @NoonSilk That was hilarious!

Answer (score 3018, accepted):

Yes, `finally` will be called after the execution of the `try` or `catch` code blocks.

The only times `finally` won't be called are:

1. If you invoke `System.exit()`
2. If you invoke `Runtime.getRuntime().halt(exitStatus)`
3. If the JVM crashes first
4. If the JVM reaches an infinite loop (or some other non-interruptable, non-terminating statement) in the `try` or `catch` block
5. If the OS forcibly terminates the JVM process; e.g., `kill -9 <pid>` on UNIX
6. If the host system dies; e.g., power failure, hardware error, OS panic, et cetera
7. If the `finally` block is going to be executed by a daemon thread and all other non-daemon threads exit before `finally` is called

Comment: Actually `thread.stop()` does not necessarily prevent `finally` block from being executed.

Comment: How about we say that the `finally` block will be called *after* the `try` block, and *before* control passes to the following statements.  That's consistent with the try block involving an infinite loop and hence the finally block never actually being invoked.

Comment: By @andrzejDoyle definition, it will return `success` first before going to `finally` block. Is that correct?

Comment: @dieend: It will decide that the return value will be success, executes the finally block, then gives back control to the calling function. Nothing will be returned if the finally block throws.

Comment: there is also another case, when we use nested **try-catch-finally** blocks

Comment: also, finally block is not called in case of exception thrown by daemon thread.

Comment: But effective java says otherwise. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=7

Comment: This is rather interesting that finally would be called when one re-throws his exception in catch() as new RuntimeException.

Comment: @BinoyBabu - That's about finalizer, not finally block

Comment: What about **Runtime#halt** ?

Comment: @AmrishPandey "finally block is not called in case of exception thrown by daemon thread" - really?? [Citation Needed], I think?

Comment: @SusanW http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java-and.html?m=1

Comment: @SusanW https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: @AmrishPandey The Oracle page doesn't mention daemons at all. The other (blogger) page discusses a JVM _terminating_, but fails to go on to show any difference vs a non-daemon thread. Reality is: on System.exit completion (incl shutdown hooks) or other termination, all threads just die where they are standing whether daemon or not: no finallys get executed either way. The blogger is incorrect where they note this as a difference ... try it yourself.

Comment: @jodonnell What if we are not using catch and throwing an exception from try. Will finally still gets executed.

Comment: @user2677679 How does this answer not include the answer to _your_ question?

Answer (score 628):

Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Test.test());
}

public static int test() {
    try {
        return 0;
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("something is printed");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
something is printed. 
0
```

Comment: FYI: In C# the behaviour is identical apart from the fact that replacing the statement in the `finally`-clause with `return 2;` is not allowed (Compiler-Error).

Comment: Here is an important detail to be aware of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20363941/2684342

Comment: IF YOU ADD CATCH BLOCK, `error: missing return statement`

Comment: You can even add a return statement in the finally block itself, which will then override the previous return value. This also magically discards unhandled exceptions. At that point, you should consider refactoring your code.

Comment: That does not really prove that finally trumps return. The return value is printed from the caller code. Doesn't seem to prove much.

Comment: @Trimtab, Yes, it's only answering the question as asked. [Tristan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20363941/1058366) clarifies that the value to return is evaluated, the `finally` block is run, and then control is returned to the caller.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a demonstration not a proof.  It is only a proof if you can show that this example always behaves this way on all Java platforms, AND that similar examples also always behave this way.

Comment: On a very off-topic side note, I'm _politically_ sure this print statement is gonna age like milk.

Comment: @JulioCezarSilva yes, the english verb _to trump_ is now a casualty of american politics.

Answer (score 427):

Also, although it's bad practice, if there is a return statement within the finally block, it will trump any other return from the regular block. That is, the following block would return false:

```
try { return true; } finally { return false; }
```

Same thing with throwing exceptions from the finally block.

Comment: This is a REALLY bad practice.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java for more info about why it's bad.

Comment: Agreed.  A return within finally{} ignores any exception thrown in try{}.  Scary!

Comment: No matter what, I always have ONLY ONE `return` statement in my methods (which is at the end), well except when its `void`.
That's what they taught me at school and I think it's a better practice too.

Comment: @dominicbri7 Why do you think it's a better practice? And why should it be different when the function/method is void?

Comment: For the same reason I NEVER use goto's in my C++ codes.
I think multiple returns makes it harder to read and more difficult to debug (of course in really simple cases it doesn't apply). I guess that's just personnal preferrence and in the end you can achieve the same thing using either method

Comment: I tend to use a number of returns when some kind of exceptional case happens. Like if(there is a reason not to continue) return;

Comment: I interpret `finally` block as a shorthand for writing the same code at the end of each `catch` block: `catch (Exc exc) { doSome(); } catch (AnotherExc exc) { doSome(); }

Comment: @MCEmperor Not the same, because as the answer states, if the `finally` block has a return statement, it will override the one in the `catch` block. You cannot do it with `catch`.

Comment: @MooBob42, should do it with embedded finallys

Comment: Very interesting example provided.

Answer (score 265):

Here's the official words from the Java Language Specification.

[14.20.2. Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)

> **A `try` statement with a `finally` block is executed by first executing the `try` block. Then there is a choice:**
>
> - If execution of the `try` block completes normally, [...]
> - If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly because of a `throw` of a value *V*, [...]
> - **If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly for any other reason *R*, then the `finally` block is executed. Then there is a choice:**
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason *R*.
>   - If the `finally` block completes abruptly for reason *S*, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason *S* (**and reason *R* is discarded**).

The specification for `return` actually makes this explicit:

[JLS 14.17 The return Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17)

> ```
> ReturnStatement:
>      return Expression(opt) ;
> ```
>
> A `return` statement with no `Expression` **attempts** to transfer control to the invoker of the method or constructor that contains it.
>
> A `return` statement with an `Expression` **attempts** to transfer control to the invoker of the method that contains it; the value of the `Expression` becomes the value of the method invocation.
>
> The preceding descriptions say "***attempts** to transfer control*" rather than just "*transfers control*" because if there are any `try` statements within the method or constructor whose `try` blocks contain the `return` statement, then any `finally` clauses of those `try` statements will be executed, in order, innermost to outermost, before control is transferred to the invoker of the method or constructor. Abrupt completion of a `finally` clause can disrupt the transfer of control initiated by a `return` statement.

Answer (score 174):

In addition to the other responses, it is important to point out that 'finally' has the right to override any exception/returned value by the try..catch block. For example, the following code returns 12:

```
public static int getMonthsInYear() {
    try {
        return 10;
    }
    finally {
        return 12;
    }
}
```

Similarly, the following method does not throw an exception:

```
public static int getMonthsInYear() {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    finally {
        return 12;
    }
}
```

While the following method does throw it:

```
public static int getMonthsInYear() {
    try {
        return 12;          
    }
    finally {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the middle case is precisely the reason why having a return statement inside a finally block is absolutely horrible (it could hide any Throwable).

Comment: Who _doesn't_ want a surpressed `OutOfMemoryError`? ;)

Comment: I tested it and it does suppress such an error (yipes!). It also generates a warning when I compile it (yay!). And you can work around it by defining a return variable and then using `return retVal` *after* the `finally` block, although that of course assumes that you suppressed some other exceptions because the code would not make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 135):

Here's an elaboration of [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65185/2684342). It's important to know that the expression to be returned is evaluated before `finally`, even if it is returned after.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Test.test());
}

public static int printX() {
    System.out.println("X");
    return 0;
}

public static int test() {
    try {
        return printX();
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("finally trumps return... sort of");
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
X
finally trumps return... sort of
42
```

Comment: Important to know.

Comment: Good to know, and makes sense as well. It seems that actually returning the value of return is what comes after `finally`. Calculating the return value (`printX()` here) still comes before it.

Comment: Nope. The code above should replace `System.out.println("finally trumps return... sort of");` with `System.out.print("finally trumps return in try"); return 42;`

Comment: This answer is completely self-evident IMO because `return` doesn't return some magic continuation that only gets evaluated if the caller prints it or whatever. `printX()` gets called before the `return` happens, regardless of any `try`/`catch`, or anything else.

Answer (score 130):

I tried the above example with slight modification-

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test());
}

public static int test() {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        i = 2;
        return i;
    } finally {
        i = 12;
        System.out.println("finally trumps return.");
    }
}
```

The above code outputs:

> finally trumps return.
>   2

This is because when `return i;` is executed `i` has a value 2. After this the `finally` block is executed where 12 is assigned to `i` and then `System.out` out is executed.

After executing the `finally` block the `try` block returns 2, rather than returning 12, because this return statement is not executed again.

If you will debug this code in Eclipse then you'll get a feeling that after executing `System.out` of `finally` block the `return` statement of `try` block is executed again. But this is not the case. It simply returns the value 2.

Comment: This example is awesome, it adds something that hasn't been mentioned in dozens finally related threads. I think barely any developer will know this.

Comment: What if `i` was not a primitive, but an Integer object.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding this case. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17 says that, "A return statement with an Expression attempts to transfer control to the invoker of the method or lambda body that contains it.... If evaluation of the Expression completes normally, producing a value V.." What I could guess from this statement is- it seems that return doesn't evaluate the expression again once it evaluates value V, that's why changed i doesn't affect the returned value, correct me.

Comment: But I coudn't found any proof regarding this, where is it mentioned that return doesn't evaluate the expression again.

Comment: @meexplorer a bit late, but it is explained in [JLS 14.20.2. Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2-100-C) - worded a bit complicated, [14.17. The return Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17-430) must also be read

Comment: @ Yamcha  It would still be same

Comment: I believe that if you added a return statement to the finally block, the value returned would be 12, not 2.  The example basically shows that the finally block is pushed onto the call stack exactly the same as calling a method - that makes a local copy of i, which reverts to 2 after the stack is popped.

Comment: When we leave off the `try` **block** , we are leaving its scope. We never enter into the scope again. So, the return value in `try`/`catch` block should be copied into somewhere to execute more code such as `finally` block. So, if there is `return` in `finally`, the return value suppress its previous return value. If not that, the back-up return value from `try`/`catch` is just used. This situation is similar with C++'s exception. In C++, when we throw an exception and catch it by *reference*, the thrown exception should be copied too because of scope of `try`.

Answer (score 53):

That is the whole idea of a finally block. It lets you make sure you do cleanups that might otherwise be skipped because you return, among other things, of course.

Finally gets called **regardless of what happens** in the try block (*unless* you call `System.exit(int)` or the Java Virtual Machine kicks out for some other reason).

Comment: That is an extremely weak answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049/715269

Answer (score 42):

A logical way to think about this is:

1. Code placed in a finally block must be executed **whatever occurs** within the try block
2. So if code in the try block tries to return a value or throw an exception the item is placed 'on the shelf' till the finally block can execute
3. Because code in the finally block has (by definition) a high priority it can return or throw whatever it likes. In which case anything left 'on the shelf' is discarded.
4. The only exception to this is if the VM shuts down completely during the try block e.g. by 'System.exit'

Comment: Is this just "a logical way to think about it" or is it really how the finally block is intended to work according to the specifications ? A link to a Sun resource would be very interesting in here.

Answer (score 22):

`finally` is always executed unless there is abnormal program termination (like calling `System. exit(0)`). so, your `System.out` will get printed.

Answer (score 19):

The finally block is always executed unless there is abnormal program termination, either resulting from a JVM crash or from a call to `System.exit(0)`.

On top of that, any value returned from within the finally block will override the value returned prior to execution of the finally block, so be careful of checking all exit points when using try finally.

Answer (score 19):

No, not always, one exception case is
`System.exit(0);`
before the `finally` block prevents `finally` to be executed.

```java
      class A {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            DataInputStream cin = new DataInputStream(System.in);

            try {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            } catch (Exception e) {
               System.exit(0); // Program terminates before executing the finally block
            } finally {
                System.out.println("Won't be executed");
                System.out.println("No error");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And that's one of the reasons you really should never call System.exit()...

Answer (score 18):

Also a return in finally will throw away any exception.  http://jamesjava.blogspot.com/2006/03/dont-return-in-finally-clause.html

Answer (score 12):

Finally is always run that's the whole point, just because it appears in the code after the return doesn't mean that that's how it's implemented. The Java runtime has the responsibility to run this code when exiting the `try` block.

For example if you have the following:

```
int foo() { 
    try {
        return 42;
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

The runtime will generate something like this:

```
int foo() {
    int ret = 42;
    System.out.println("done");
    return 42;
}
```

If an uncaught exception is thrown the `finally` block will run and the exception will continue propagating.

Answer (score 12):

## NOT ALWAYS

The Java Language specification describes how `try`-`catch`-`finally` and `try`-`catch` blocks work at [14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)
In no place it specifies that the `finally` block is always executed.
But for all cases in which the `try`-`catch`-`finally` and `try`-`finally` blocks complete it does specify that before completion `finally` must be executed.

```
try {
  CODE inside the try block
}
finally {
  FIN code inside finally block
}
NEXT code executed after the try-finally block (may be in a different method).
```

The JLS does not guarantee that **FIN** is executed after **CODE**.
The JLS guarantees that if **CODE** and **NEXT** are executed then **FIN** will always be executed after **CODE** and before **NEXT**.

Why doesn't the JLS guarantee that the `finally` block is always executed after the `try` block? *Because it is impossible.* It is unlikely but possible that the JVM will be aborted (kill, crash, power off) just after completing the `try` block but before execution of the `finally` block. There is nothing the JLS can do to avoid this.

Thus, any software which for their proper behaviour depends on `finally` blocks always being executed after their `try` blocks complete are bugged.

`return` instructions in the `try` block are irrelevant to this issue. If execution reaches code after the `try`-`catch`-`finally` it is guaranteed that the `finally` block will have been executed before, with or without `return` instructions inside the `try` block.

Comment: My apologies for commenting on such an old answer, but I don't think saying `any software which for their proper behaviour depends on finally blocks always being executed after their try blocks complete are bugged.` is quite right. `finally` blocks are usually used for resource clean-up to prevent leaks. How else would you do it? In the same vein, you cannot (or should not...) catch `Error`s either, as there is (usually) no reasonable way for a normal application to handle them.

Comment: @user991710 If clean-up in the finally block is in example about closing an open file then not executing the finally block is not a problem, the OS closes it on program termination. If clean-up is deletion of a file that is a problem, the OS won't do it when the program is aborted before finally. If another part of the system depends on the java program always doing such deletion then the system in general and the java program in particular are bugged. You can't rely on finally always executing. You can only rely on the guarantee that finally has already been executed if NEXT has been executed

Comment: Interesting take, although it forces some parts of your design as far as I can see. To expand on your deletion example: would you have a kind of 'reaper' task running that is responsible for deletion (clean-up) of files? I admit that, given your explanation, using `finally` may (given enough time, likely *will*) cause bugs, but is the additional development (and testing) time worth the potentially unnoticeable improvement in stability? More generally: does the amount of care that should go into a particular design depend on the subsystem in question? Time is a valuable resource, after all. :)

Comment: @user991710 There is nothing wrong with using finally. You just need to know what it does and what it does not. For the particular case of deleting a file I would actually do it in the finally block. But being aware that doing so provides no guarantee (not even if the last line of the try block finished executing) I would take precautions to deal which such situation. So deleting previous leftover files as a first step of executing the program, if this is a service style program which would be re-run automatically. If system failing in such situation is of no concern then, sure, don't bother

Answer (score 10):

Yes it will get called. That's the whole point of having a finally keyword. If jumping out of the try/catch block could just skip the finally block it was the same as putting the System.out.println outside the try/catch.

Answer (score 10):

Because a finally block will always be called unless you call `System.exit()` (or the thread crashes).

Answer (score 10):

This is because you assigned the value of i as 12, but did not return the value of i to the function. The correct code is as follows:

```
public static int test() {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        return i;
    } finally {
        i = 12;
        System.out.println("finally trumps return.");
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Concisely, in the official Java Documentation (Click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)), it is written that -

> If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then
>   the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing
>   the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may
>   not execute even though the application as a whole continues.

Answer (score 10):

> Answer is simple **YES**.

**INPUT:**

```
try{
    int divideByZeroException = 5 / 0;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("catch");
    return;    // also tried with break; in switch-case, got same output
} finally {
    System.out.println("finally");
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
catch
finally
```

Comment: Answer is simple NO.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy How? Can you explain please?

Comment: read the accepted answer, the original question is about 'Will it always execute' and it will not always. In your case it will but this does not answer the original question and may even be misleading beginners.

Comment: then in which case it wont get execute?

Comment: In all cases mentioned in other answers, see accepted answer with 1000+ upvotes.

Answer (score 10):

`finally` block is always executed and before returning `x`'s (calculated) value.

```
System.out.println("x value from foo() = " + foo());

...

int foo() {
  int x = 2;
  try {
    return x++;
  } finally {
    System.out.println("x value in finally = " + x);
  }
}
```

Output:

> x value in finally = 3
> x value from foo() = 2

Comment: Nice illustrative example, +1.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it will. No matter what happens in your try or catch block unless otherwise System.exit() called or JVM crashed. if there is any return statement in the block(s),finally will be executed prior to that return statement.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to [@vibhash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/296053/4298200) as no other answer explains what happens in the case of a mutable object like the one below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test().toString());
}

public static StringBuffer test() {
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        s.append("sb");
        return s;
    } finally {
        s.append("updated ");
    }
}
```

Will output

> ```
> sbupdated
> ```

Comment: As of Java 1.8.162, this is not the output.

Answer (score 8):

Yes It will.
Only case it will not is JVM exits or crashes

Answer (score 8):

Yes, finally block is always execute. Most of developer use this block the closing the database connection, resultset object, statement object and also uses into the java hibernate to rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 8):

`finally` will execute and that is for sure.

`finally` will not execute in below cases:

case 1 :

When you are executing `System.exit()`.

case 2 :

When your JVM / Thread crashes.

case 3 :

When your execution is stopped in between manually.

Answer (score 8):

I tried this,
It is single threaded.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Object obj = new Object();
    try {
        synchronized (obj) {
            obj.wait();
            System.out.println("after wait()");
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    } finally {
        System.out.println("finally");
    }
}
```

The `main` `Thread` will be on `wait` state forever, hence *`finally` will never be called*,

so console output will not `print` `String`: after `wait()` or `finally`

Agreed with @Stephen C, the above example is one of the 3rd case mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049/2987755):

Adding some more such infinite loop possibilities in following code:

```
// import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        // Thread.currentThread().join();
        // new Semaphore(0).acquire();
        // while (true){}
        System.out.println("after sleep join semaphore exit infinite while loop");
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    } finally {
        System.out.println("finally");
    }
}
```

Case 2: If the JVM crashes first

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        unsafeMethod();
        //Runtime.getRuntime().halt(123);
        System.out.println("After Jvm Crash!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        System.out.println("finally");
    }
}

private static void unsafeMethod() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);
    unsafe.putAddress(0, 0);
}
```

Ref: [How do you crash a JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65200/2987755)

Case 6: If `finally` block is going to be executed by daemon `Thread` and all other non-daemon `Threads` exit before `finally` is called.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                printThreads("Daemon Thread printing");
                // just to ensure this thread will live longer than main thread
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                System.out.println("finally");
            }
        }
    };
    Thread daemonThread = new Thread(runnable);
    daemonThread.setDaemon(Boolean.TRUE);
    daemonThread.setName("My Daemon Thread");
    daemonThread.start();
    printThreads("main Thread Printing");
}

private static synchronized void printThreads(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
    int threadCount = 0;
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    for (Thread t : threadSet) {
        if (t.getThreadGroup() == Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup()) {
            System.out.println("Thread :" + t + ":" + "state:" + t.getState());
            ++threadCount;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Thread count started by Main thread:" + threadCount);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
}
```

output: This does not print "finally" which implies "Finally block" in "daemon thread" did not execute

> ```
> main Thread Printing  
> Thread :Thread[My Daemon Thread,5,main]:state:BLOCKED  
> Thread :Thread[main,5,main]:state:RUNNABLE  
> Thread :Thread[Monitor Ctrl-Break,5,main]:state:RUNNABLE   
> Thread count started by Main thread:3  
> -------------------------------------------------  
> Daemon Thread printing  
> Thread :Thread[My Daemon Thread,5,main]:state:RUNNABLE  
> Thread :Thread[Monitor Ctrl-Break,5,main]:state:RUNNABLE  
> Thread count started by Main thread:2  
> -------------------------------------------------  
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Comment: See the accepted answer.  This is just an edge case of "infinite loop".

Answer (score 8):

Consider the following program:

```
public class SomeTest {

    private static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(someString());
        System.out.println("---AGAIN---");
        System.out.println(someString());
        System.out.println("---PRINT THE RESULT---");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    private static String someString() {

        try {
            sb.append("-abc-");
            return sb.toString();

        } finally {
            sb.append("xyz");
        }
    }
}
```

As of Java 1.8.162, the above code block gives the following output:

```
-abc-
---AGAIN---
-abc-xyz-abc-
---PRINT THE RESULT---
-abc-xyz-abc-xyz
```

this means that using `finally` to free up objects is a good practice like the following code:

```
private static String someString() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        sb.append("abc");
        return sb.toString();

    } finally {
        sb = null; // Just an example, but you can close streams or DB connections this way.
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sb.setLength(0)` in finally?

Comment: sb.setLength(0) will just empty the data in the StringBuffer. So, sb = null will disassociate the object from the reference.

Comment: Shouldn't "xyz" be printed twice in the output? Since the function was called twice, why "finally" was only once?

Comment: @fresko : finallly is definitely called twice but when it comes to the output in the console it will only show once because of the return statement. You can run the program and see the output, and after that add another statement `System.out.println(sb.toString());`

Comment: This isn't a good practice. That finally block with `sb = null;` just adds unneeded code. I understand that you mean that a `finally` block is a good place to free resources like a database connection or something like that, but have in mind that your example could confuse newcomers.

Comment: @Samim Thanks, I added the lines 
        `System.out.println("---AGAIN2---");`
        `System.out.println(sb);`
and it's more clear now. As it was, the output was against your thesis :p
I also added to your answer, but the edit must be accepted by a moderator or somebody like that. Else you can add them

Answer (score 7):

That's actually true in any language...finally will always execute before a return statement, no matter where that return is in the method body. If that wasn't the case, the finally block wouldn't have much meaning.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the point about return in finally replacing a return in the try block, the same is true of an exception.  A finally block that throws an exception will replace a return or exception thrown from within the try block.

Answer (score 7):

I was very confused with all the answers provided on different forums and decided to finally code and see. The ouput is :

**finally will be executed even if there is return in try and catch block.**

```
try {  
  System.out.println("try"); 
  return;
  //int  i =5/0;
  //System.exit(0 ) ;
} catch (Exception e) {   
  System.out.println("catch");
  return;
  //int  i =5/0;
  //System.exit(0 ) ;
} finally {  
   System.out.println("Print me FINALLY");
}
```

**Output**

> try
>
> Print me FINALLY

2. If return is replaced by `System.exit(0)` in try and catch block in above code and an exception occurs before it,for any reason.

Answer (score 7):

1. Finally  Block always get executed. Unless and until
   **System.exit()** statement exists there (first statement in finally block).
2. If **system.exit()** is first statement then finally block won't get executed and control come out of the finally block.
   Whenever System.exit() statement gets in finally block till that statement finally block executed and when System.exit() appears then control force fully come out of the finally block.

Comment: This has been answered many times, so which new information does your answer add?

Answer (score 6):

If an exception is thrown, finally runs. If an exception is not thrown, finally runs. If the exception is caught, finally runs. If the exception is not caught, finally runs.

Only time it does not run is when JVM exits.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't handle exception, before terminating the program, JVM executes finally block. It will not executed only if normal execution of program will fail mean's termination of program due to these following reasons..

1. By causing a fatal error that causes the process to abort.
2. Termination of program due to memory corrupt.
3. By calling System.exit()
4. If program goes into infinity loop.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, because **no control statement** can prevent `finally` from being executed.

Here is a reference example, where all code blocks will be executed:

```
| x | Current result | Code 
|---|----------------|------ - - -
|   |                |     
|   |                | public static int finallyTest() {
| 3 |                |     int x = 3;
|   |                |     try {
|   |                |        try {
| 4 |                |             x++;
| 4 | return 4       |             return x;
|   |                |         } finally {
| 3 |                |             x--;
| 3 | throw          |             throw new RuntimeException("Ahh!");
|   |                |         }
|   |                |     } catch (RuntimeException e) {
| 4 | return 4       |         return ++x;
|   |                |     } finally {
| 3 |                |         x--;
|   |                |     }
|   |                | }
|   |                |
|---|----------------|------ - - -
|   | Result: 4      |
```

In the variant below, `return x;` will be skipped. Result is still `4`:

```
public static int finallyTest() {
    int x = 3;
    try {
        try {
            x++;
            if (true) throw new RuntimeException("Ahh!");
            return x; // skipped
        } finally {
            x--;
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return ++x;
    } finally {
        x--;
    }
}
```

References, of course, track their status. This example returns a reference with `value = 4`:

```
static class IntRef { public int value; }
public static IntRef finallyTest() {
    IntRef x = new IntRef();
    x.value = 3;
    try {
        return x;
    } finally {
        x.value++; // will be tracked even after return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`try`- `catch`- `finally` are the key words for using exception handling case.
 
As normal explanotory

```
try {
     //code statements
     //exception thrown here
     //lines not reached if exception thrown
} catch (Exception e) {
    //lines reached only when exception is thrown
} finally {
    // always executed when the try block is exited
    //independent of an exception thrown or not
}
```

The finally block  prevent executing...

- When you called `System.exit(0);`
- If JVM exits.
- Errors in the JVM

Answer (score 5):

The finally block will not be called after return in a couple of unique scenarios: if System.exit() is called first, or if the JVM crashes.

Let me try to answer your question in the easiest possible way.

**Rule 1** : The finally block always run
 (Though there are exceptions to it. But let's stick to this for sometime.)

**Rule 2** : the statements in the finally block run when control leaves a try or a catch block.The transfer of control can occur as a result of normal execution ,of execution of a break , continue, goto or a return statement, or of a propogation of an exception.

In case of a return statement specifically (since its captioned), the control has to leave the calling method , And hence calls the finally block of the corresponding  try-finally structure. The return statement is executed after the finally block.

In case there's a return statement in the finally block also, it will definitely override the one pending at the try block , since its clearing the call stack.

You can refer a better explanation here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/.... the concept is mostly same in all the high level languages.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is written [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

> If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.

Comment: So when you say yes you mean no?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code, you will understand the **code in finally block is get executed after return statement**.

```
public class TestTryCatchFinally {
    static int x = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(f1());
        System.out.println(f2());
    }
    
    public static int f1() {
        try {
            x = 1;
            return x;
        } finally {
            x = 2;
        }
    }
    
    public static int f2() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally block always execute whether exception  handle or not .if any exception occurred before try block then finally block will not execute.

Answer (score 3):

Because the final is always be called in whatever cases you have. You don't have exception, it is still called, catch exception, it is still called

Answer (score 3):

Consider this in a normal course of execution (i.e without any Exception being thrown): if method is not 'void' then it always explicitly returns something, yet, finally always gets executed

Answer (score 3):

`finally` can also be exited prematurely if an `Exception` is `throw`n inside a *nested `finally` block*. The compiler will warn you that the `finally` block does not complete normally or give an error that you have unreachable code. The error for unreachable code will be shown only if the `throw` is not behind a conditional statement or inside a loop.

```
try {
} finally {
   try {
   } finally {
      // if (someCondition) --> no error because of unreachable code
      throw new RunTimeException();
   }

   int a = 5; // unreachable code
}
```

Comment: Just noting that this is completely normal behavior. Any/all code exits prematurely if an exception is thrown. This is no different than an exception thrown anywhere else. There is no special rule in the spec that says "exceptions cannot be used inside a finally block." Because of this, I even misunderstood your answer at first and almost gave -1, until I reread it a couple times.

Comment: Well, but how is a return different from a throw? If you return then the block should return but in a finally block, the return will be postponed and there are some weird exception for return, so it isn't clear that finally handles throw in a normal way.

That is the main reason why I wrote this back then.

Also throw in a try or catch block won't hinder the finally block from execution, so ofc. one might expect that when you throw in a finally block it still executes.

Comment: "how is return different from throw?" In a few ways, none of which are relevant here. In a finally block, return is not postponed, or did you mean the return in the try-block being postponed until after finally-block executes (in which case, yes that is true)? Either way, the same holds for thrown exceptions. No matter what happens in a `try`, when the end of `try` is reached, the control passes to `finally`, then all the same rules apply within the `finally` (with any try/catch inside of finally operating as they usually would).

Comment: I am not saying your answer is wrong or useless or anything like that. It is technically correct. I merely noted that the behavior you describe is nothing that breaks the try/finally rule which is simply "No matter what happens in `try/catch`, once they are done control flow ***will*** pass to the finally block" The try/finally guarantee is essentially nothing more, nothing less than that. Within any block, be it try/catch/finally or otherwise, you can within it nest other try/catch/finally blocks as you suggest. Indeed, some people are unaware of that.

Answer (score 3):

Same with the following code:

```
static int f() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            return 1;
        } finally {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 2;
}
```

f will return 2!

Comment: Duplicative answer

Comment: But this shows that anyhow finally block is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will always be called but in one situation it is not called when you use `System.exit()`.

```
try {
    // risky code
} catch (Exception e) {
    // exception handling code
}
finally() {
    // It is always executed, but if before this block there is any statement like System.exit(0); then this block will not be executed.
}
```

Comment: Duplicative answer

Comment: Not only 'duplicative' but self-contradictory.

Answer (score 2):

finally block is executed always even if you put a return statement in the try block. The finally block will be executed before the return statement.

Answer (score 2):

Finally is always called at the end

when you try, it executes some code, if something happens in try, then catch will catch that exception and you could print some mssg out or throw an error, then finally block is executed.

Finally is normally used when doing cleanups, for instance, if you use a scanner in java, you should probably close the scanner as it leads to other problems such as not being able to open some file

Answer (score 2):

Here are some conditions which can bypass a finally block:

1. If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute. More on [sun tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)
2. Normal Shutdown - this occurs either when the last non-daemon thread exits OR when Runtime.exit() ([some good blog](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/jvm-shutdown-jvm-shutdown-sequence.html)). When a thread exits, the JVM performs an inventory of running threads, and if the only threads that are left are daemon threads, it initiates an orderly shutdown. When the JVM halts, any remaining daemon threads are abandoned finally blocks are not executed, stacks are not unwound the JVM just exits. Daemon threads should be used sparingly few processing activities can be safely abandoned at any time with no cleanup. In particular, it is dangerous to use daemon threads for tasks that might perform any sort of I/O. Daemon threads are best saved for "housekeeping" tasks, such as a background thread that periodically removes expired entries from an in-memory cache ([source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601))

Last non-daemon thread exits example:

```
public class TestDaemon {
    private static Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Is alive");
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    // throw new RuntimeException();
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                System.out.println("This will never be executed.");
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread daemon = new Thread(runnable);
        daemon.setDaemon(true);
        daemon.start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        // daemon.stop();
        System.out.println("Last non-daemon thread exits.");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
Last non-daemon thread exits.
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
Is alive
```

Answer (score 1):

try-with-resoruce example

```
static class IamAutoCloseable implements AutoCloseable {
    private final String name;
    IamAutoCloseable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void close() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

@Test
public void withResourceFinally() {
    try (IamAutoCloseable closeable1 = new IamAutoCloseable("closeable1");
         IamAutoCloseable closeable2 = new IamAutoCloseable("closeable2")) {
        System.out.println("try");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("finally");
    }
}
```

Test output:

```
try
closeable2
closeable1
finally
```

Answer (score 1):

the total list of situations are like :

1. 'System.exit()' method call within 'try' or 'catch' block can prevent 'finally' block from executing.
2. Infinite loops or endless operations within 'try' or 'catch' block can prevent 'finally' block from executing.
3. Power failures, hardware failures, or abrupt termination of the program may prevent 'finally' block from executing.
4. JVM crashes may prevent 'finally' block from executing.
5. 'Thread.stop()' method call can prevent 'finally' block from executing.
6. Errors in JVM or operating system can prevent 'finally' block from executing.
7. 'StackOverflowError' or 'OutOfMemoryError' can prevent 'finally' block from executing.
8. 'IllegalMonitorStateException' can prevent 'finally' block from executing in the context of a synchronized block.
9. 'SecurityException' or other security-related exceptions can prevent 'finally' block from executing.
10. Bugs or logical errors in the program can prevent 'finally' block from executing correctly.
    e.g:

```java
try {
     Object obj = null;
    obj.toString(); // NullPointerException error
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Exception handling...
} finally {
    // This may not execute correctly due to the NullPointerException error
    System.out.println("This may not execute correctly due to a NullPointerException error.");
}
```

Comment: The finally block in your example for number 10 does execute.

Answer (score 0):

I am terribly late to answer here, but I am surprised that no one mentioned the Java debugger option to drop a stack frame.  I am a heavy user of this feature in IntelliJ.  (I am *sure* Eclipse and NetBeans has support for the same feature.)

If I drop stack frame from a the try or catch block that is followed by a finally block, the IDE will prompt me: "Shall I execute the finally block?"  Obviously, this is an artificial runtime environment -- a debugger!

To answer your question, I would say you can only guarantee it runs if ignore when a debugger is attached, and (like others said) method `something()` does not (a) call Java method `System.exit(int)` or (b) C function `exit(int)` / `abort()` via JNI or (c) do something crazy like call `kill -9 $PID` on itself(!).

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049/1554195) is true in nearly all aspects, but it is still only halve the truth at all (ok, 95% of the truth).

Assume the following code:

```
private final Lock m_Lock = new ReentrantLock();
…
public final SomeObject doSomething( final SomeObject arg )
{
  final SomeObject retValue;
  try
  {
    lock.lock();
    retValue = SomeObject( arg );
  }
  finally
  {
    out.println( "Entering finally block");
    callingAnotherMethod( arg, retValue );
    lock.unlock();
  }
  
  return retValue;
}
…
try
{
   final var result = doSomething( new SomeObject() );
}
catch( final StackOverflowError e ) { /* Deliberately ignored */ }
```

Calling the method `doSomething()` will cause a `StackOverflowError` nearly immediately.

And the `lock` will not be released!

But how could this happen when the `finally` block is always executed (with the exceptions already listed in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049/1554195))?

That is because there is *no guarantee* made that *all* statements in the `finally` block are *really* executed!

This would be obvious if there would be a call to `System.exit()` or a `throws` statement before the call to `lock.unlock()`.

But there is nothing like that in the sample code …

Aside that the two other method calls in the `finally` block before the call to `lock.unlock()` will cause another `StackOverflowError` …

And voilà, the lock is not released!

Although the sample code as such is silly, similar patterns can be found a lot in many kinds of software. All works fine as long as nothing ugly happens in the `finally` block …

Funny fact is that it does not work in later versions of Java (meaning that in later versions, the lock was released …). No idea when and why this changed.

But you still have to make sure that the `finally` block always terminates normally, otherwise it might not matter if (that) it always get executed …