# Java Dynamic multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a multidimensional array dynamically. The number of rows is fixed but the number of columns is changed dynamically. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: You can google "dynamic multidimentional array java"

Comment: try `ArrayList` dynamic growable array

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104504/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-build-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-java

Answer (score -2):

You could use an arraylist like this
`Arraylist<Object[nbRow]>`