# how to create a user defined multidimensional vector

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

i was trying to create a program for my matrix theory class that lets you enter your own matrix and do a scaler multiplication, my question is how do you let the user pick the dimensions of the vector my first thought was to create a switch case statement with a bunch of options but it's not very dynamic.

```
switch (dimensions) {
      case 1:
          Vector[] matrix1 = new Vector[2];
            break;
      case 2: 
          Vector[][] matrix2 = new Vector[2][2];
            break;
      case 3:
          Vector[][][] matrix3 = new Vector[2][2][2];
      default:

            break;
    }
```

im not looking for any code to be written for me I'm just not sure if this is the right direction or not thank you for any help

Comment: Do you expect arbitrary dimensionality or is there a fixed maximum number of dimensions?  For just 3 possible values, what you have seems OK to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating them is not the only problem,
(you can do it using reflection 
http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/reflect/array/newInstance.html)
but later you need to use them, and without knowing their types, it's painfull.

Matrix is a two-dimensional structure, so 3-dimensions is not necessery.
Also 1-dimension (vector) could be seen as a single row Matrix.
So you only need Vector[].

Comment: Your right I was looking at it the wrong way thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer of this question can be useful:

[Is it possible to dynamically build a multi-dimensional array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104504/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-build-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-java)

Basically, you create a "multi-dimensional" array using:

```
java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int... dimensions)
```

For example:

```
int numberOfDimensions = 3;
int[] dims = new int[numberOfDimensions];
for (int i = 0; i < dims.length; i++) {
    dims[i] = 2;
}

Object multiDimensionalArray = Array.newInstance(Vector.class, dims);
```

And then you fill it with values using more reflection and recursion.

In the end, it's probably better to restrict the user to a fixed number of dimensions and stick to the `switch` block.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to define your own class to represent an array with variable dimensions.  Implementing the class isn't trivial, though.

I'd take advantage of Java's "variable arity" methods:

```
public class DynamicDimensionArray {

    public DynamicDimensionArray(int... dimension) {
        // code
    }
```

This lets callers do things like

```
DynamicDimensionArray vector = new DynamicDimensionArray(10);  // one-dimensional
DynamicDimensionArray matrix = new DynamicDimensionArray(3, 5); // two-dimensional
DynamicDimensionArray fiveDim = new DynamicDimensionArray(2, 3, 2, 10, 4);
     // five-dimensional
```

Inside the constructor, `dimension` is actually treated as an `int[]`.  So `dimension.length` gives you the number of dimensions.

So how would you implement the class?  I think the simplest way (which isn't really that simple) is to have private variable that is a 1-dimensional array of your type (let's assume it's a `double`).  The number of elements is obtained by multiplying the elements in the `dimension`:

```
    private double[] data;

    public DynamicDimensionArray(int... dimension) {
        int totalElements = 1;
        for (int dim : dimension) {
             totalElements *= dim;
        }
        data = new double[totalElements];
    }
```

Then implementing the rest of the class depends on what operations you want to support.  You might want a `getElement` method to get one element of the array:

```
public double getElement(int... index) {
    // ???
}
```

As before, `index` will be an `int[]` inside the method.  You'd check to make sure the length matches the length of the original `dimension` and throw an exception if not.  The trick will be converting the indexes to an index you can use in your one-dimensional `data`.  The basic formula (assuming all indexes are 0-relative) looks like this:

If it's a 1-dimensional array with dimensions *d*<sub>0</sub>, and the indexes are *i*<sub>0</sub>, the index into `data` is just *i*<sub>0</sub>.

If it's a 2-dimensional array with dimensions (*d*<sub>1</sub>, *d*<sub>0</sub>), and the indexes are (*i*<sub>1</sub>, *i*<sub>0</sub>), the index into `data` is *i*<sub>1</sub>*d*<sub>0</sub> + *i*<sub>0</sub>.

If it's a 3-dimensional array with dimensions (*d*<sub>2</sub>, *d*<sub>1</sub>, *d*<sub>0</sub>), and the indexes are (*i*<sub>2</sub>, *i*<sub>1</sub>, *i*<sub>0</sub>), the index into `data` is *i*<sub>2</sub>*d*<sub>1</sub>*d*<sub>0</sub> + *i*<sub>1</sub>*d*<sub>0</sub> + *i*<sub>0</sub>.

And so on... you should be able to see the pattern.

Look up "row-major order" in Wikipedia for more information.

It's not trivial, though; so if you're limited to a small number of dimensions, such as 3, then you should consider Tim's comment that using a `switch` might be OK.