# How to set the dimensions of a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I don't know if it is a duplicate of [Is it possible to dynamically build a multi-dimensional array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104504/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-build-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-java) because I don't know the

```
Array.newInstance(Array.class, 5);
```

method and I couldn't find an answer I understood on that question either but the 2 questions are definitely about the same topic

I want a multi-dimensional array to store the inputs and the inputs size is defined in the constructor like this

```
 double[[]] inputs;
 public AI(int[] inputSize) {
    inputs = new double[inputSize];
 }
```

I know the [[]] doesn't exist but is there an alternative?

(I tried to remove most of the context since I think the question will be more straightforward to answer this way)

EDIT : to be clear I don't want double[][] I want double[][][]... where the number of [] equals inputSize.size 
so for example :
inputSize = {5,3,2,1}; => inputs = new double[5][3][2][1];

Comment: Do you mean `[][]`?

Comment: @AndrewL. I believe he wants `double[][][]...` where the number of [] is dynamic. In which case... hmm. I don't know. Never thought about it before! I'm leaning towards "that's not possible" but I'm sure someone has a clever solution (which potentially doesn't involve strict arrays)

Comment: @nasukkin I was talking about `[[]]`, `[][]` is valid

Comment: @nasukkin Yes that is what I want the number of [] would equal inputSize.length