# How to make a method that can accept different multidimensional arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make a program that does calculations on different multidimensional arrays, or really just the simple task of printing it.
I am hoping to have the function parameters that sort of look like

```
printArray(Int Array of any dimensions, int dimensions, int... sizes)
```

One goal for calculations is the mode, so I am thinking of flattening out all the arrays to do any calculations or modifications.

I've looked into how arrays and stream can be used to flatten out an array.

2d:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).flatMap(Arrays::stream).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray();
```

3d:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).flatMap(Arrays::stream).flatMap(Arrays::stream).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray();
```

but it also is not generic since every dimension it requires another "`.flatMap`". And I still don't know how to make that kind of parameters that accept any dimensions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104504/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-build-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-java, anyway what is wrong with (dynamic) ArrayList ?

Comment: I think the stream is not where you should solve this. Rather, think about how you could represent this as a class and pass one of those in.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the trick:

```
var arrStr = Arrays.stream(arr);
    
var counter = 0;
while(dimensions > counter)
{
    arrStr = arrStr.flatMap(Arrays.stream);
}
return arrStr.flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray();
```

Admittedly this is rather of an imperative style and may be improved on.

Comment: I don't think this works, because the stream type changes (to one less dimension) every time `flatMap` is called. You could try making the variable a raw stream.

Comment: @Bohemian you're probably right, but as you said this can be dealt with.