# How to intialize a Float Array in Java with its shape given in the form of int[]?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to initialize a `float[][][]` object in Java. For instance,

```
float[][][] x = new float[1][2][3]
```

As you can see the integers 1, 2 and 3 are known by default. Now I have a `int[]` defining these numbers ( dimensions ) of the array like,

```
int[] shape = { 1 , 64 , 64 , 3 }
```

From this array, how can I build an object like,

```
float[][][][] y = new float[1][64][64][3]
```

**Note: The length of the `shape` object is not predefined. Hence the dimensions of the resulting `float[]` object will also vary.**

> How do we dynamically create a `float` matrix ( like `float[][]` or even `float[][][]` ) from a given `int[]` which defines its shape.

Comment: Maybe you can use Object[]...[] instead of float[]...[]. In this case you can simply add new dimensions while iterate shape array and then cast the resulting matrix of objects to matrix of floats. This is just an idea

Comment: You could use the [newInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int...)) method to create such an array but you would have to use `Float` instead of `float` for your element type and I'm not sure how you could dynamically cast it to an array of variable dimensions.

Comment: What do you need it for? You couldn't actually use the array in your code, since you couldn't express the compile-time type of the array with a variable number of dimensions. You would constantly need reflection to use it.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104504/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-build-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-java/3104931#3104931) it appears to be possible to modify the array after it is created by recursing through each dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can do reflection to create the array and then type-cast it to make it useful.

```
float[][][][] x = (float[][][][]) Array.newInstance(Float.TYPE, shape);
```

This assumes that you at least know the number of dimensions upfront.

If you don't know that, you can still create the array, but you cannot cast it to a static type anymore (it will just be an `Object`). This will make it hard to write code that uses the array.