# How can I reproduce EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW error in Java

Tags: java, crash, jvm, stack-overflow, crash-dumps

How can I reproduce EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW error in Java.

PS: I am not talking of StackOverflowError Error in Java which gracefully shuts the JVM. I am talking of EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW in error.log which cause JVM to crash.

Comment: please double check your *PS*, I guess there's a tiny *not* missing in between "am" and "talking" ...

Comment: Most `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW` errors I found so far happen in native code outside the JVM... If there was one *inside*, it would be a bug and to be fixed.

Comment: Not exact answer, but somehwat is there at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200/how-do-you-crash-a-jvm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW` errors I found so far happen in native code outside the JVM. A crash *inside* the JVM is worth a bug report and will be fixed. Or are you in need of an (unknown) exploit?

So the easist and most reliable way would be to write a native library with some code that causes the JVM to crash and call that with JNI.

(general answer, I actually don't know how to do it exactly. Can't be done with java code only ;) )

Comment: +1. I can do +1 only but wanted to do +100 for confirming my understanding. Most of the others has mentioned about StackOverFlowError!

Answer (score 4):

Blow stack:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    main(null);
}
```

Blow heap:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(true) list.add(new String("boom"));
}
```

Comment: None of the above would cause JVM crash. First one will cause StackOverflowError and second would cause OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void stackoverflow()
{
     stackoverflow();
}
```

Call it, and enjoy :D

Comment: This would cause StackOverflowError and not JVM crash!