# Infinite 100% CPU usage at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)

Tags: java, jvm, cpu-usage, infinite-loop

I'm right now debugging a program which has two threads per one external process, and those two threads keep on reading Process.getErrorStream() and Process.getInputStream() using a `while ((i = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) >= 0)` loop.

Sometimes when the external process crashes due to a JVM crash (see [these hs_err_pid.log files](https://gist.github.com/2405004)), those threads which read the stdout/stderr of that external process begin consuming 100% CPU and never exit. *The loop body is not being executed* (I've added a logging statement there), so the infinite loop appears to be inside the native method `java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes`.

I've reproduced this on both Windows 7 64-bit (jdk1.6.0_30 64-bit, jdk1.7.0_03 64-bit), and Linux 2.6.18 (jdk1.6.0_21 32-bit). The code in question is [here](http://code.google.com/p/pitestrunner/source/browse/pitest/src/main/java/org/pitest/util/StreamMonitor.java?r=9210fd33a879c17af2f94b5d94b72ddbaf345a02#38) and it is used [like this](http://code.google.com/p/pitestrunner/source/browse/pitest/src/main/java/org/pitest/util/JavaProcess.java?r=9210fd33a879c17af2f94b5d94b72ddbaf345a02#43). See those links for the full code - here are the interesting bits:

```
private final byte[]              buf = new byte[256];
private final InputStream         in;
...    

int i;
while ((i = this.in.read(this.buf, 0, this.buf.length)) >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

The stack traces look like

```
"PIT Stream Monitor" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000008869800 nid=0x1f70 runnable [0x000000000d7ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    - locked <0x00000007c89d6d90> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at org.pitest.util.StreamMonitor.readFromStream(StreamMonitor.java:38)
    at org.pitest.util.StreamMonitor.process(StreamMonitor.java:32)
    at org.pitest.util.AbstractMonitor.run(AbstractMonitor.java:19)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

or

```
"PIT Stream Monitor" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000008873000 nid=0x1cb8 runnable [0x000000000e3ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220)
    at org.pitest.util.StreamMonitor.readFromStream(StreamMonitor.java:38)
    at org.pitest.util.StreamMonitor.process(StreamMonitor.java:32)
    at org.pitest.util.AbstractMonitor.run(AbstractMonitor.java:19)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

With the Sysinternals Process Explorer I was able to get native stack traces of those threads. Most often, over 80% of the time, the stack trace looks like this:

```
ntdll.dll!NtReadFile+0xa
KERNELBASE.dll!ReadFile+0x7a
kernel32.dll!ReadFile+0x59
java.dll!handleRead+0x2c
java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x1d1
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d
```

This also happens quite often:

```
ntdll.dll!RtlNtStatusToDosErrorNoTeb+0x52
ntdll.dll!RtlNtStatusToDosError+0x23
KERNELBASE.dll!GetCurrentThreadId+0x2c
KERNELBASE.dll!CreatePipe+0x21a
kernel32.dll!ReadFile+0x59
java.dll!handleRead+0x2c
java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x1d1
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d

ntdll.dll!RtlNtStatusToDosErrorNoTeb+0x42
ntdll.dll!RtlNtStatusToDosError+0x23
KERNELBASE.dll!GetCurrentThreadId+0x2c
KERNELBASE.dll!CreatePipe+0x21a
kernel32.dll!ReadFile+0x59
java.dll!handleRead+0x2c
java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x1d1
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d
```

And sometimes it's executing this part of the code:

```
java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0xc3
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d

java.dll!Java_sun_io_Win32ErrorMode_setErrorMode+0x847c
java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0xd7
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d

jvm.dll!JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs+0x1829f
java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x128
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d

jvm.dll+0x88c1
jvm.dll!JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs+0x182a7
java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x128
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d

java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x10b
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d

jvm.dll!JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x1423
java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x190
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d

jvm.dll+0x88bf
jvm.dll!JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x147d
java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x190
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d

java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x1aa
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d

java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x1c3
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d

java.dll!VerifyClassCodesForMajorVersion+0x224
java.dll!Java_java_io_FileInputStream_readBytes+0x1d
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Is this a known problem with the JVM? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Could you include your loop code? BTW the condition `>= 0` is overly broad, if `buf.length` is non-zero, then read() is guaranteed to read at least 1 byte or return -1 (or throw an Exception).

Comment: What? Is `Process.getInputStream()` returning a FileInputStream?

Comment: Yes. In java.lang.ProcessImpl#ProcessImpl you can see stdout_stream and stderr_stream being initialized with a FileInputStream. It kinda makes sense from the Unix point of view, where everything is a file.

Comment: Looking at OpenJDK's source code, the implementation of readBytes has no loops and is a thin wrapper over Windows' ReadFile function. Let's continue looking into OS issues... maybe antivirus or something...

Comment: Is it reproducible on another machine (maybe even on another operating system)?

Comment: I'm getting similar symptoms - the system slowing down very much - on our CI server which runs on Linux. I haven't yet gotten a stack trace from there, because I don't have shell access to those machines, but I'll try to reproduce it on some other machine.

Comment: This issue might be related: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2009/09/28/reading-stdin-may-cause-your-jvm-hang

Comment: Slowing down due to blocking (which might be related to non-draining of the output stream of the child process) or also 100% cpu usage on one thread?

Comment: This problem happens also on Linux 2.6.18 and Java 1.6.0_21 32-bit.

Comment: I added sample hs_err_pid.log files which show what kind of a JVM crash happens in the child process whose stdout/stderr the problematic threads were reading. They are here, both for Windows and Linux: https://gist.github.com/2405004

Comment: @EskoLuontola: on Linux, do you also get 100% cpu usage in this case or only blocked threads?

Comment: Yes. Also on Linux those threads hog the CPU.

Comment: Can you attach gdb to get a (native) stack traces here aswell?

Comment: Can anyone familiar with the eclipse codebase comment on if/how eclipse works around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've not yet been able to reproduce this locally, but the two possible workarounds might be

- Play around with `in.available()`.
- Redirect *stout* and *stderr* in the external process to a socket and
  read this from the controlling process instead.

Comment: [A quick fix using in.available()](http://code.google.com/p/pitestrunner/source/browse/pitest/src/main/java/org/pitest/util/StreamMonitor.java?spec=svn0607ac947dd76768f5e852350386bc9c324a6005&r=0607ac947dd76768f5e852350386bc9c324a6005#59) has helped to avoid the problem for now. We are still looking for a better solution and the reason why this is happening in the first place. I'll try to produce a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) by removing superfluous code from the closed source project where I can reproduce this.

Comment: The problem can be re-produced by crashing the child process with the infinite array allocating loop from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200/how-do-you-crash-a-jvm and probably the other techniques listed there.