# Swing application upgrade from Java 1.7 to 1.8

Tags: java, swing, migration, java-8, java-7

I need to migrate my swing application from Java 1.7 to 1.8. 
Application only works for Window environment.

Did this Java upgrade especially for swing API cause any feature stop working or any of its UI components behaviour change?

Comment: Not that I've seen yet

Comment: *"Application only works for Window environment."*  That is likely a bug in the code used.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @Andrew, I mean the application is only suppose to work for window, not yet compatible with Mac or Linux so we will be only testing it with windows environment.

Comment: @PankajDubey - Still a bug :-)

Comment: "*Did this Java upgrade especially for swing API*" [Definately not](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html).

Comment: Of course, there are no intentional breakdowns. And the [Known Issues for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-known-issues-2157115.html) section does not list any known Swing/Windows issue. So everything else will only revealed by *testing* your application in the target environment.

Answer (score 1):

There was an interesting bug report on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072883/java-swing-jwindow-application-crash) recently. But seems that the situation described in that question is very specific. We successfully migrated our quite huge Java 7 Swing application to Java 8. There were only several minor things to fix not related to Swing. In particular some complex generic parameters may work in Java 7, but produce a compilation error in Java 8. After several months of using Java 8 no Swing-related problems were noticed in our application.