# How to produce compiled code segmentation fault in java?

Tags: java, jvm

I have seen the question like [how-do-you-crash-a-jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200/how-do-you-crash-a-jvm) and [shortest-code-that-raises-a-sigsegv](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-raises-a-sigsegv)
There are some java code to produce SIGSEGV like:

```
final Constructor<Unsafe> unsafeConstructor = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
unsafeConstructor.setAccessible(true);
final Unsafe unsafe = unsafeConstructor.newInstance();
System.out.println(unsafe.getAddress(0));
```

and it produces a SIGSEGV typed `V`(VM frame).

```
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1e2440]
```

And there is `Crash in Compiled Code` according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/crashes001.html.

I wonder if there anyway to produce a typed `J` segmentation fault.
And I have seen some lib issue like [JVM crash](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/issues/426).(So it indicates that can be manually produced?)

Comment: What is "typed J segmentation fault"?

Comment: @talex `Crash in Compiled Code` .It means crash happened in java frame(The example V is VM fame).

Comment: There is no java code that can produce it. You have to corrupt some internal structures using native code or unsafe.

Comment: @talex Thx~ Using Unsafe to produce is ok for the question.Other codes using Unsafe just produce crash in VM frame so I want to see how can Unsafe be used to produce crash in java frame. Before asking, I tried to use Unsafe to assign int field an object instance(or other different types) and get it using getter...But the code worked fine without any error...

Comment: You have to know internal structure of JVM to understand how to do it. I don't posses such knowledge.

Comment: A crash on a `J` method indicates a bug in the JVM or a corruption of the JVM.  This is much harder to recreate.

Comment: @talex Thx anyway :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, and I found one from slideshare https://www.slideshare.net/AndreiPangin/do-we-need-unsafe-in-java (p53) but  can't reproduce directly (Put random buffer size and addr get V frame)

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a program that reproduces a crash in compiled code.

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Crash extends Thread {
    static volatile Object obj = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Crash().start();

        // Give some time to compile run() method
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);

        // Overwrite Object's class field, so that 'instanceof' cannot work
        unsafe.putInt(obj, 8L, -1);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!(obj instanceof Runnable)) {
            // Loop until crash
        }
    }
}
```

So how it works. (Or it would be right to say "how it *doesn't* work" :)

1. Run a thread with an infinite loop. This loop is obviously "hot", so the method gets JIT-compiled.
2. `instanceof` check cannot be optimized away, since `obj` is volatile.
3. After some time we spoil `obj` header by writing garbage to its class field at offset #8.
4. This breaks the compiled code, because `instanceof` check relies on the object class.

And here what we'll get.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000000368b6ad, pid=9660, tid=0x00000000000032f0
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_192-b12) (build 1.8.0_192-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.192-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 38% C2 Crash.run()V (13 bytes) @ 0x000000000368b6ad [0x000000000368b640+0x6d]
#
```

Comment: That's amazing,I never thought to use Unsafe like that,thx a lot. :)

Answer (score 3):

When the JVM crashes like this, it shows you the actual stack trace after inlining. This means methods which have been inlined don't appear.

What you can do is run a test where this code is warmed up to the point where Unsafe is inlined, then you can trigger a crash which will appear to come from a Java method, however, it's just that the real cause has been inlined.