# finally and return

Tags: java, try-catch, finally

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, does return trump finally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally)

In the below example,

```
class ex8
{
    public void show()
    {
        try
        { 
            int a=10/0;
            return;
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e)
        {    
            System.out.println(e);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Finally");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ex8().show();
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Finally
```

How is it that Finally gets printed in spite of return statement in catch?