# Is it possible to use return statement in try block?. how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch

Is it possible to use return statement in try block?.How,What is the use of the statement.

Comment: -1 for not bothering to try

Comment: i had problem in my system...so i cant now.

Comment: You've already been given the correct answer below. I just want to point out that even if you do have a return statement in a try block, any finally block will still execute.

Comment: @Ayyappan.Anbalagan: If you have "a problem in your system" that's preventing you from running any code, why do you need to know this right now?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen, They are parallelizing the "fix computer" and "learn C#" event loops.

Comment: Mr.Matti Virkkunen..
Today, i got this question in my technical round interview...

Comment: @Ayyappan.Anbalagan: What computer are you using to post anyways? Did the "problem in your system" mysteriously disappear?

Comment: +1 While you could have tried it out, this is an interesting question.

Comment: To all the downvoters, "trying it out" is not the most reliable technique, it is unlikely to reveal all pre- and post-conditions. This might be a duplicate but otherwise it's a good and valid question.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: In that case it would've been better to ask "what are the possible pitfalls" instead of just asking "can I do it"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can return from within a try block, but keep in mind that the code in the finally clause will be executed before returning from the method.  For example, calling `MessageBox.Show(test().ToString());` using the method below will cause two message boxes to appear (the first displaying "3" and the second displaying "1").

> ```
>     int test()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             return 1;
>             throw new Exception();
>         }
>         catch (Exception e)
>         {
>             return 2;
>         }
>         finally
>         {
>             MessageBox.Show("3");
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Note also that attempting to return from the finally clause results in a compiler error.

Comment: +1 to both the answer and the comment for learning me something about the finally block today.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can use return in a try block, and the syntax is just like everywhere else.

```
try
{
    return 0;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I can use local variables without having to widen their scope, for example.

```
int Foo(string bar) {
    try {
        int biz = int.Parse(bar);

        return biz;
    } catch(...) {
        // Handle bad `bar`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer for this question is Yes.
As an example for this you can refer to the following question:
[finally and return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824746/finally-and-return)
Hope you also get a clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can do it like:

```
public string X(..)
{
    try
    {
        //do something
        return value;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       throw;
       //or return here
    }
}
```

Comment: It's important that you either throw or return in the catch block. If the try code throws an exception, the return in the try block will not be executed.