# Will the statements inside finally get executed if they are following return?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, does return trump finally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally)

Wondering if finally statement will still get executed if it is after return statement?

Comment: Can you give a code example ? As it, the question seems a little too fuzzy to me

Comment: And what hinders you simply testing it instead of asking a yes-no-question here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it will the only exception is `System.exit(1)` in try block

Comment: which is something you usually don't wanna do :-)

Answer (score 4):

yes finally will get executed even if you `return`

```
public static void foo() {
        try {
            return;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Finally..");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo();
   }
```

Output:

```
Finally..
```

Answer (score 1):

Not if the return statement is before its associated try block.

Yes if the return statement is inside the associated try block.

```
public void foo(int x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        return; // finally block won't be executed for negative values

    System.out.println("This message is never printed for negative input values");
    try
    { 
        System.out.println("Do something here");
        return;    
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("This message is always printed as long as input is >= 0");
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, 'finally' comes into the picture only if code enters 'try' block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finally will be executed though it is after `return` statement.

Comment: Please refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824746/finally-and-return

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ofcourse. Finally statement is designed to be executed in any cases if execution will go into try statement.

Answer (score 0):

finally block will fail only when we terminate JVM by calling `System.exit(int)` or  `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the other answers, if there is a return in your finally block, statements after the return will not be executed.

```
finally
    {
        System.out.println("In finally");
        if ( 1 == 1 )
            return;
        System.out.println("Won't get printed.);
    }
```

In the above snippet, "In finally" is displayed while "Won't get printed" isn't.