# Does code in finally get run after a return in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, exception, try-catch-finally

Consider the following code:

```
@try {
  if (something.notvalid)
  {
    return;
  }
  // do something else
} @catch (NSException *ex) {
  // handle exception
} @finally {
  NSLog(@"finally!");
}
```

If `something` is not valid and I return from within the try, does the code in `@finally` execute or not?  I believe that it should but others I've spoken to don't think so and I'm unable to test this at the moment.

Comment: whats the conclusion? will it execute or not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@finally code always executes according to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html) and [here](http://www.macosxguru.net/article.php?story=20060827093013582).

> A @finally block contains code that
>   must be executed whether an exception
>   is thrown or not.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Oddly enough, it does. I'm not sure why, but I just built a test and tried a number of configurations and every time it did.

Here were the configs:

- Return in try block: stopped execution of try block and caused finally to be executed
- Return in try block and return in finally: stopped execution of try and stopped execution in finally block and the entire method.
- Return in finally block: functioned like normal return outside of a try/catch/finally block.

Comment: The first case is not odd. That's the point of `finally`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally.

Comment: You see, I would expect for `return` to go beyond the scope of the `try/catch/finally` block and apply to the method. I'm not saying it's wrong that it does that, but it DID catch me off-guard. It's just something I've never paid attention to. I guess I've always carried my methods all the way through to the end ;)

Answer (score 2):

With the RAI definition, Finally block will anyhow executed with that code scope, for particular resource.

It has a close meaning with Object's `~Destructor`. As same as an object's `~Destructor` always executes, finally block also executes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Even if there was an `Exception` within `catch` block, `finally` will be executed.

If you are familiar with C++, just think `finally` as the `destructor` of an `object`. What ever the state of a statement within the object, `~Destructor` will be executed.
But you cant put `return` within `finally`[some compilers allow though].

See the code below: See how global variable `y` been changed.
Also see how `Exception1` been covered by `Exception2`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace finallyTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static int y = 0;
        static int testFinally()
        {
            int x = 0;
            try
            {
                x = 1;
                throw new Exception("Exception1");
                x = 2;
                return x;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                x = -1;
                throw new Exception("Exception2", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                x = 3;
                y = 1;
            }
            return x;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">>>>>" + testFinally());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { Console.WriteLine(">>>>>" + e.ToString()); }
            Console.WriteLine(">>>>>" + y);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
    >>>>>System.Exception: Exception2 ---> System.Exception: Exception1
   at finallyTest.Program.testFinally() in \Projects\finallyTest\finallyTest\Program.cs:line 17
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at finallyTest.Program.testFinally() in \Projects\finallyTest\finallyTest\Program.cs:line 24
   at finallyTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in \Projects\finallyTest\finallyTest\Program.cs:line 38
>>>>>1
```

Comment: because the question is about ObjC and tagged as #objective-c. shouldnt the example be in ObjC instead C#?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a sample snippet, the output is

try!
catch!
finally!

```
@try {
    NSLog(@"try!");

    NSException *e = [NSException
                      exceptionWithName:@"No Name"
                      reason:@"No Reason"
                      userInfo:nil];
    @throw e;


} @ catch (...)
{
    NSLog(@"catch!");
    return;
}
@finally
{
    NSLog(@"finally!");
}

NSLog (@"other code");
```