# Why do we use finally blocks?

Tags: java, .net, finally

As far as I can tell, both of the following code snippets will serve the same purpose. Why have `finally` blocks at all?

Code A:

```
try { /* Some code */ }
catch { /* Exception handling code */ }
finally { /* Cleanup code */ }
```

Code B:

```
try { /* Some code */ }
catch { /* Exception handling code */ }
// Cleanup code
```

Comment: This is not specific to C# it is a .Net question

Comment: No more needed with java7: AutomaticResourceManagement, try(new resourceDeclartion()){}

Answer (score 156, accepted):

- What happens if an exception you're not handling gets thrown? (I hope you're not catching `Throwable`...)
- What happens if you return from inside the try block?
- What happens if the catch block throws an exception?

A `finally` block makes sure that *however* you exit that block (modulo a few ways of aborting the whole process explicitly), it will get executed. That's important for deterministic cleanup of resources.

Comment: Not necessarily true; finally won't get executed if (1) there's a `System.exit()` call (2) there's an infinite loop in the try or one of the catch block (3) I pull the plug on the computer

Comment: yeah they seem to be valid resons for having finally.

Comment: Can someone explain "What happens if you return from inside the return block"? Where is the return block?

Comment: @Alon 
try{
 return 1;
}finally{
 retrun 2;
}

You will get 2

Comment: @NullUserException: Hence the "modulo a few ways..." bit

Comment: @Alon: Typo, sorry - should have been "try block"

Comment: John Skeet lives here on stackoverflow, every question is like a doorbell ringing he has to answer :)

Comment: @EdS. [midnight to 6 AM](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/566/131713) (requires 10k rep on Meta)

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049/8031521) discusses the (rare) conditions under which finally WON'T be called.

Comment: `What happens if the catch block throws an exception` - then `finally` won't be called, so no difference from not having `finally`. In reality, unless you use `return` within your `try` block, `finally` is useless.

Comment: @vitaly-t: No, that's not true. If the `catch` block throws an exception, `finally` still executes. For example, try https://gist.github.com/jskeet/70a8666b737612d01269f2405128b72c `finally` blocks are very *very* far from useless, whether or not you return within the `try` block.

Comment: @vitaly-t: See also [JLS 14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2): "If the catch block completes abruptly for reason R, then the finally block is executed."

Comment: @JonSkeet I've been testing it under Node.js v12, and `finally` does not execute, if an error is thrown inside `catch`. That was the reason why I wrote my first comment.

Comment: @vitaly-t: Unless you mean you've been invoking Java from Node.js, you're talking about Javascript. This question is about Java and .NET. It may be that finally isn't useful in Javascript, but it *definitely* is in both Java and .NET.

Comment: @vitaly-t: And even in Javascript it looks like it's executed: https://js.do/code/348783 Do you have a similar example I could run that shows the finally block *not* being executed?

Answer (score 14):

Note that (in Java at least, probably also in C#) it's also possible to have a `try` block without a `catch`, but with a `finally`. When an exception happens in the `try` block, the code in the `finally` block is run before the exception is thrown higher up:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("somefile.xyz");
try {
    somethingThatMightThrowAnException();
}
finally {
    // cleanup here
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You may want to put the code that you want to anyway get executed irrespective of what happens in your try or catch block.

Also if you are using multiple catch and if you want to put some code which is common for all the catch blocks this would be a place to put- but you cannot be sure that the entire code in try has been executed.

For example:

```
conn c1 = new connection();
try {
    c1.dosomething();
} catch (ExceptionA exa) {
    handleexA();
    //c1.close();
} catch (ExceptionB exb) {
    handleexB();
    //c1.close();
} finally {
    c1.close();
}
```

Comment: What if I do not use 'finally' but close the connection ?

Answer (score 5):

Finally always gets executed, where as your code after the catch may not.

Comment: why not! If the exception is handled properly the code will get executed definitly.

Comment: @Nadeem: See my answer for 3 reasons it may not happen.

Answer (score 3):

Still scrolling down? Here you go!

This question gave me tough time back a while.

```
try
{
 int a=1;
 int b=0;
 int c=a/b;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 console.writeline(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
 console.writeline("Finally block");
}
console.writeline("After finally");
```

what would be printed in the above scenario?
Yes guessed it right:

- ex.Message--whatever it is (probably attempted division by zero)
- Finally block
- After finally

  ```
  try
  {
      int a=1;
      int b=0;
      int c=a/b;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      throw(ex);
  }
  finally
  {
      console.writeline("Finally block");
  }
  console.writeline("After finally");
  ```

What would this print? Nothing! It throws an error since the catch block raised an error.

In a good programming structure, your exceptions would be funneled, in the sense that this code will be handled from another layer. To stimulate such a case i'll nested try this code.

```
try
{    
 try
    {
     int a=1;
     int b=0;
     int c=a/b;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
     throw(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
     console.writeline("Finally block")
    }
    console.writeline("After finally");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 console.writeline(ex.Message);
}
```

In this case the output would be:

- Finally block
- ex.Message--whatever it is.

It is clear that when you catch an exception and throw it again into other layers(Funneling), the code after throw does not get executed. It acts similar to just how a return inside a function works.

You now know why not to close your resources on codes after the catch block.Place them in finally block.

Comment: That's the first answer that really answers why finally blocks are needed, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Even though our application is closed forcefully there will be some tasks, which we must execute (like memory release, closing database, release lock, etc), if you write these lines of code in the `finally` block it will execute whether an exception is thrown or not...

Your application may be a collection of threads, `Exception` terminates the thread but not the whole application, in this case `finally` is more useful.

In some cases `finally` won't execute such as JVM Fail, Thread terminate, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need that code to execute regardless of any exceptions that may be thrown.  For example, you may need to clean up some unmanaged resource (the 'using' construct compiles to a try/finally block).

Answer (score 0):

`finally` ALWAYS executes, unless the JVM was shut down, `finally` just provides a method to put the cleanup code in one place.

It would be too tedious if you had to put the clean up code in each of the `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There may be times when you want to execute a piece of code no matter what. Whether an exception is thrown or not. Then one uses `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

If catch block throws any exception then remaining code will not executed hence we have to write finaly block.

Answer (score 0):

finally block in java can be used to put "cleanup" code such as closing a file, closing connection etc.

---

The finally block will not be executed if program exits(either by calling System.exit() or by causing a fatal error that causes the process to abort).