# In java,what if both try and catch throw same exception and finally has a return?

Tags: java, exception

```
public class Abc {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Abc.method());
    }

    static int method() {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        finally {
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the return value 4?

Comment: try block is for doing some task, if the task cannot be completed ,vthen throw exception from catch Block. you should not throw exceptions in try.

Answer (score 14):

That's the way `finally` works. The snippet

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

will complete *abruptly*, but the finally clause will kick in and when it returns it *discards* the original reason for completing the statement.

This is explained in section [Blocks and Statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.20.2) in the Java Language Specification. I've highlighted the relevant path in your situation:

> A `try` statement with a
>   `finally` block is executed
>   by first executing the
>   `try` block. Then there is
>   a choice:
>
> - If
>     execution of the `try`
>     block completes normally, then the
>     `finally` block is
>     executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - ...
>
>   **If execution
>     of the `try` block
>     completes abruptly because of a
>     `throw` of a value
>     *V*, then there is a choice:**
>
>   - **If
>       the run-time type of *V* is
>       assignable to the parameter of any
>       `catch` clause of the
>       `try` statement, then the
>       first (leftmost) such
>       `catch` clause is selected.
>       The value *V* is assigned to the
>       parameter of the selected
>       `catch` clause, and the
>       *Block* of that
>       `catch` clause is executed.
>       Then there is a choice:**
>
>     - If the
>         `catch` block completes
>         normally, then the
>         `finally` block is
>         executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>       - ...
>
>       **If the
>         `catch` block completes
>         abruptly for reason *R*, then the
>         `finally` block is
>         executed. Then there is a choice:**
>
>       - If the
>           `finally` block completes
>           normally, then the `try`
>           statement completes abruptly for
>           reason *R*.
>
>         **If the `finally`
>           block completes abruptly for reason
>           *S*, then the `try`
>           statement completes abruptly for
>           reason *S* (and reason *R*
>           is discarded).**
>
>     If the run-time type of *V*
>       is not assignable to the parameter of
>       any `catch` clause of the
>       `try` statement, then the
>       `finally` block is
>       executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>     - ...
>
>   If execution of the
>     `try` block completes
>     abruptly for any other reason
>     *R*, then the
>     `finally` block is
>     executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>   - ...

Comment: +1, more details than I wanted to know. What will happen if it had a `return` in `try`?

Comment: The finally would still kick in and discard the previous reason for completing the statement.

Comment: There's a no `finally` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You should never return from a finally block. This is very bad practice. See [Java try-finally return design question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185340/java-try-finally-return-design-question) and [Does finally always execute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally/65949).

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions on StakOverflow that explain this.

To make it simple: if you put a return or a throw statement in a finally clause this is the last action of your method. Generally speaking this is a bad practice though.

Answer (score 1):

Finally will always return 4.  The finally block will always execute regardless of any exception that is throw in the try and catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the finally block returns a value causes the thrown exception to be swallowed, so it wont propagate out of the method.