# Exception not thrown on divide by zero in catch block

Tags: java, exception, divide-by-zero

While playing with exception handling in Java I noticed that no exception is thrown when 
some illegal runtime operation is being done in the **catch** block in Java.

Is that a bug in the language or am I missing something ?
Could someone please look into it - as in why no exception is thrown from the catch block.

```
public class DivideDemo {

    @SuppressWarnings("finally")

    public static int divide(int a, int b){

    try{
       a = a/b;
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e){
       System.out.println("Recomputing value");

       /* excepting an exception in the code below*/
       b=0;
       a = a/b;
       System.out.println(a);
    }
    finally{
      System.out.println("hi");
      return a;
    }
  }    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Dividing two nos");
     System.out.println(divide(100,0));
  }
```

}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is that a bug in the language or am I missing something ?

It's because you have `return` statement in your `finally` block:

```
finally {
  System.out.println("hi");
  return a;
}
```

This `return` statement effectively swallows exception and "*overrides it*" with returned value.

## See also

- [Java try-finally return design question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185340)

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz , so technically, anything can be done inside the catch if covered by a return statement. Should that not be a defect in the language?  ( just brainstorming )

Comment: @SHOUBHIKBOSE -- It's "working as designed".  It's a very bad idea to have a return statement in a finally block, but the language will let you do it.  (No computer language can prevent you from doing stupid things.)

Comment: Thanks .I wonder why the language allows one to do so ? [ I mean what could possibly be the reason for this design decision ]

Comment: @SHOUBHIKBOSE for example, you open a Stream in a try code section and close it in the finally (to free the resources even if there was an error in the try block, +1!), but you have a return at the end of the try block, so should the resources be kept in memory?

Comment: @SHOUBHIKBOSE In competent hands it can be useful. For example, it could be a conditional return (inside `if`) that handles a specific situation where this would actually conform to a contract. On the other hand, you don't really need a decision **not** to include a special rule. The current state only shows the lack of any decision.

Comment: If you remove @SuppressWarnings("finally"), you see Eclipse warning: "finally block does not complete normally". The right way is to avoid warning not to suppress it.