# Exception is swallowed by finally

Tags: java, exception

```
static int retIntExc() throws Exception{
    int result = 1;
    try {
        result = 2;
        throw new IOException("Exception rised.");
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        result = 3;
    } finally {
        return result;
    }
}
```

A friend of mine is a .NET developer and currently migrating to Java and he ask me the following question about this source. In theory this must `throw IOException("Exception rised.")` and the whole method `retIntExc()` must `throws Exception`. But nothing happens, the method returns 2.

I've not tested his example, but I think that this isn't the expected behavior.

EDIT: Thanks for all answers. Some of you have ignored the fact that method is called `retIntExc`, which means that this is only some test/experimental example, showing problem in throwing/catching mechanics. I didn't need 'fix', I needed explanation why this happens.

Comment: Why don't you declare it `throws IOException`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally

Comment: @BoltClock, how's that relevant?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is why you can't return from a finally block in C# :)

It's absolutely the behaviour laid out in the Java Language Specification though. It's specified in [section 14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).

> If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and the throw of value V is discarded and forgotten).

Returning is one example of completing abruptly; if the `finally` block threw an exception, that would *also* complete abruptly, losing the original exception.

The quote above was from this nested set of bullet points, leaving out the options which aren't applicable here:

> - If execution of the try block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V, then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the run-time type of V is not assignable to the parameter of any catch clause of the try statement, then the finally block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>     - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and the throw of value V is discarded and forgotten).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed - JLS reference.

Comment: yet to be fixed in Java 17 LTS?

Comment: @Pacerier: I'm not sure what you mean by "fixed" - isn't it already behaving as specified?

Answer (score 3):

It will return `2` because

**`finally` always execute**

Comment: -1 **finally does not always execute** and it doesn't print anything.

Comment: please try this. System.out.println(retIntExc()); and please think twise before voting anything!

Comment: finally actually doesn't always execute.

Answer (score 2):

The `finally` block executes no matter what exception is thrown. It doesn't just execute after the exceptions are caught by the `catch` blocks you declare. It executes after the `try` block *and exceptions caught if any*. If your method throws an exception, it can't return anything unless you swallow it within your method and return `result`. But you can't have both.

Also, unless your method has any other code, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will never be encountered either.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you issue a return statement before the exception is passed trough and thus a valid value is returned. You cannot both return a value and throw an exception.

Removing the finally block around the return will give the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

The *IOException* class is not a child of the *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* class so the catch part will be never executed.

If you change to it this it will return 3.

```
static int retIntExc() throws Exception{
        int result = 1;
        try {
            result = 2;
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ("Exception rised.");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            result = 3;
        } finally {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this wouldn't be expected behaviour. By the end of this code block result is equal to 2.

```
static int retIntExc() throws Exception{
        int result = 1;
        try {
            result = 2;
```

You then throw an exception, but your catch block catches exceptions of a different type so nothing is executed.

```
        throw new IOException("Exception rised.");
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
          ...
    }
```

The finally block is guaranteed to be executed, so the final step is to return 2.

This successful return overrules the bubbling exception. If you want the exception to continue to bubble then you must not return in the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

By putting `return` in finally method you override thrown exception and result is returned instead. Your code should be something like this:

```
static int retIntExc() throws Exception{
        int result = 1;
        try {
            result = 2;
            throw new IOException("Exception rised.");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            result = 3;
        } finally {
            // do something
        }
        // it gets here only when exception is not thrown
        return result;
    }
```