# How to Handle Lost Exception in java

Tags: java, exception

In the following code two exceptions [FatalException and MyException] are thrown.
The Trivial Myexception (overwrites?) Makes the FatalException to be lost. how?

how to handle this situation?

```
    try{
        try {
        throw new FatalException("Important");
        } 
    finally
    {              
          throw new MyException("trivial");
    }
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

without the catch class for inner try block.

(Article Mentioned its a flaw Exceptions in java!) so there should be someway to overcome it? maybe recent standards changed it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4711064/335858

Comment: The way to handle it is: don't write code like this.

Comment: @Matt Ball: not my code, i read about this!

Comment: Then what is the question? If you can't change the code, there's nothing you can do but live with the behavior as it's defined.

Comment: That's the way it works, if you foolishly write it that way.  You shouldn't throw an exception in finally.

Comment: @HotLicks what to do about `connection.close()`? (SQL)

Comment: If you need to execute an operation in finally that may raise an exception, you should surround it with its own try range to suppress the exception.

Comment: @HotLicks oh I know, I just wanted it for OP's benefit.

Comment: Java 7 try-with-resources includes a facility for *suppressed exceptions*, where exceptions from closing resources are attached to exceptions from the try block. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html#suppressed-exceptions

Comment: What you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to handle this elegantly: `finally` takes over the control in Java, letting you do whatever you want, [even return normally from a `try` block that threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4711097/335858).

If you must handle the inner exception, you need to write a lot of potentially fragile code for it:

```
Exception important = null;
try{
    try {
        important = new FatalException("Important");
    } finally {
        if (important != null) throw important;
        throw  new MyException("trivial");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your best solution is not to write code like that.

Comment: You are right , he needs a potentially fragile code to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the order of execution. The initial `throw` for all intents and purposes is the defacto `return` statement for the method (Read: exit point) but because it is inside a `try` block with a `finally` block the code inside the `finally` block is *guaranteed* to be run before the method returns ([with a few exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516049/in-java-is-the-finally-block-guaranteed-to-be-called-in-the-main-method/516060#516060)). So before the methods `return`/`throw` another, different exception is thrown which is a newer, sooner method return.

The way to handle this situation it to never get in it. You should be aware that this is how Java behaves and avoid programming yourself in this corner.

Comment: it is not a guarantee that it will run.  What if i pull the power source before the finally gets executed?

Comment: @Woot4Moo if you pull the power source, the method return will also not happen.

Comment: right so your statement is incorrect.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I am technically correct, as I said that it is guaranteed to be run before the **method returns**. I did not say anything about when the method fails to return.

Comment: you aren't even technically correct.  I can terminate the process at any point and invalidate your statement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this could be the correct structure of how you could nest the exceptions.

```
try
{
    // Some codes to be tried over here.
}
catch(FatalException fe)
{
    System.out.println("Fatal Exception occurred.");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error! ");
}
catch(MyException me){}
```

In this manner, the exceptions could be caught accordingly.

Comment: Order matters, MyException would never be hit unless it extends Throwable.

Comment: The  catch(Exception) cathes all exceptions and no more catch 'll be executed.