# Effect of "finally" block on return values from "try" block

Tags: java

I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114212/questions-every-good-java-java-ee-developer-should-be-able-to-answer) and I got the following code snippet:

```
public void testFinally(){
    System.out.println(setOne().toString());

}

protected StringBuilder setOne(){
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
    try{
        builder.append("Cool");
        return builder.append("Return");
    }finally{
        builder.append("+1");
    }
}
```

**The answer is:** CoolReturn+1

Okay then I tried the same with `String` and `int` following is my code snippet with `String`:

```
public void testFinally(){
    System.out.println(setOne().toString());
}

protected String setOne(){
    String str = "fail";
    try{
        str = "success";
        return str;
    }finally{
        str = str + "fail";
    }
}
```

Why the **answer is:** `success`. Why not `successfail`, as in 1st case finally appends value and here I am doing concatenation?

Also I tried with primitive type `int`

```
public void testFinally(){
    System.out.println(setOne());
}

protected int setOne(){
    int value = 10;
    try{
        value  = 20;
        return value ;
    }finally{
        value  = value  + 10;
    }
}
```

Here too why the **answer is:** 20 why not 30.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030858/why-does-changing-the-returned-variable-in-a-finally-block-not-change-the-return 


You can refer to this post for more details..

Comment: I have read answers and they are saying `StringBuilder` object points to same reference so we can change then what if I made the reference to `null` why I am still getting `ReturnCool` as answer why not `null`

Comment: @Vishrant If you make the reference `null`, you change the value of the reference variable to `null`. If you just modify the `StringBuilder` itself, you don't change the value of the reference variable at all. It still points to the same object. Think of the variable as an integer that holds a memory address of an object.

Comment: @JasonC that question refers to some Class object which are immutable, this is about primitive types as well.

Comment: @Vishrant `StringBuilder` is not a primitive and is mutable, that's the difference, and the reason of this behaviour.

Comment: @Vishrant It's precisely the same question (and answer), even if the examples are different. An `int` is an `int`, a reference variable is a memory address. The rules are the same. Think of a reference variable almost like you are returning an `int` that is an index into an array of data. You can change the data in that array from the `finally` block, but the *index* returned cannot be changed. Later, if you access the array at that index, you will see the changes the `finally` block made to the data, but the value returned was not changed. Primitives and reference values are the same.

Comment: Note that immutability is irrelevant to the general concept here. It makes no difference if the return is an `int` equal to 42, a `double` equal to 98.6, or a memory address equal to `0x12345678`. The value returned cannot be modified by a `finally` block, although a `finally` block can certainly modify any other data it wishes, including the data that a returned memory address happens to point to. That question is the same as this, and the answer is identical.

Comment: @JasonC: It is interesting to see this discussion, isn't immutability means preventing state (of object) change? as you said, in second case assuming String is NOT immutable, shouldn't statement in finally simply change the state of object rather than pointer?

Comment: @Nambari Assuming strings were mutable for the sake of discussion: No, not in the way it was written, at least, because you would never expect a binary `+` operator to modify the fields of its left operand (e.g. even if strings had, say, an `append()` method, `a = a + b` would not be expected to modify any fields of `a`, it would be expected to return a *new* object then store a reference to that in `a`, leaving the original `a` untouched). Bear in mind that one source of confusion here is that Java allows `+` on `String` as a convenience; no other objects directly support operators like that.

Comment: (^ Not counting automatic unboxing of primitive wrapper types).

Comment: @JasonC: I missed that + part. I just took String part didn't pay much attention to other stuff. Now your point "immutability is irrelevant to the general concept" make sense because + operator here.

Comment: @Vishrant You appear to be lacking a fundamental understanding of the concept that a reference variable *points to an object*, and that the *value* of a reference variable is nothing more than a memory address. This can be a difficult concept to wrap your head around at first, but once you do, the behavior of these examples will become very clear. Check out good old https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vm5MNP7pn5g for a quick overview of references in Java; that may give you some ideas to start thinking about here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first and second methods return the reference to the object, the `finally` block is executed later, what happens in the first example is that you still keep the reference to the object (the builder) so you can modify it.

In the second example you have a string, which also is inmutable, so you are not able to modify it, only assign it a new object to the variable. But the object which you have returned is not modified. So when you do `str = str + "fail";` you assign to your variable `str` a new object.

In the third example you have an integer, which is not an object, it returns it´s value, later in the `finally` block you assign your variable to a new integer, but the returned one is not modified

**Detailed explanation:**

Imagine a fourth case:

```
    public static class Container{
    public int value = 0;
}

protected static Container setOne(){
    Container container = new Container();
    try{
        container.value  = 20;
        return container ;
    }finally{
        container.value  = container.value + 10;
    }
}
```

This function retrieves the reference to a variable called container, and after returning it it increments the container's value field to +10, so when you exit the function, the container.value will be at 30, just like in the StringBuilder example.

Let´s compare this method with the third example (the int method):

If you get the bytecode of this two methods you get:

**For the example of the int:**

```
bipush 10
istore_0
bipush 20
istore_0
iload_0
istore_2
iinc 0 10
iload_2
ireturn   <- return point  
astore_1
iinc 0 10  <- retrieve the variable value and add 10 to it's value
aload_1  <- Store the value of the result of the sum.
athrow
```

**For the example of the Container wrapper class:**

```
new Test4$Container
dup
invokespecial Test4$Container/<init>()V
astore_0
aload_0
bipush 20
putfield Test4$Container/value I
aload_0
astore_2
aload_0
aload_0
getfield Test4$Container/value I
bipush 10
iadd
putfield Test4$Container/value I
aload_2
areturn  <-- Return point
astore_1 <-- Stores the reference
aload_0
aload_0
getfield Test4$Container/value I <-- gets the value field from the object reference
bipush 10 
iadd      <-- add the value to the container.value field
putfield Test4$Container/value I <-- Stores the new value (30) to the field of the object
aload_1
athrow
```

As you can see, in the second case the `finally` statement access to the referenced variable incrementing it's value. but in the `int` example it only adds 10 to the value of the variable, assigning a new value to the variable.

I've used this example because it's bytecode is easier to be read than the stringbuffer one, but you can do it with it and you will have a similar result.

Comment: +1. This is well put. What need to be returned is already cached after execution of return.. statement, in Stringbuilder case through reference, code in finally updated cached value, remaining cases updates are not effective on cached value.

Comment: This has nothing to do with immutability.

Comment: +1, this is what I was going for in my answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was trying to explain that string objects cannot be modified, it was poorly explained, I´ve edited it ;)

Comment: Edited with a detailed explanation

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR**: You've already told the method what to return. The `finally` block happens *after* you've done that. Additionally, reference variables are just pointers to objects, and while the `finally` block can't change the reference itself, it can certainly change the object that the reference points to.

Long answer:

There are two things going on here:

---

First, you've already told the method what *value* to return. The JLS states it fairly simply, from [14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) (emphasis mine):

> A try statement with a finally block is executed by **first executing the try block**.

That is, the `try` block executes completely before the `finally` block is run. Also, from [14.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17):

> ... execution of such a return statement **first evaluates the Expression**.

The implication is that any and all effects the `try` block had (including specifying the value that the method should return) are complete, and that the value to be returned has been completely evaluated and is now "set in stone", so to speak.

Let's concentrate on this first. Here, we look at a slightly modified version of your primitive example. The original example you posted isn't a great example, because the initial value `10` of the integer plus the `10` in the finally block *also* happens to equal 20, which clouds what is truly happening. So let's consider this instead:

```
protected int setOne(){
    int value = 5;
    try{
        value = 20;
        return value;
    }finally{
        value = value + 10;
    }
}
```

The return of this method is 20. Not 15, not 30, but 20. Why? Because in the `try` block, you set `value = 20`, then you tell the method to return 20; `value` is evaluated in the `return` statement, and its value at that time is 20. Nothing the `finally` block does can change the fact that you've already told the method to return 20.

Ok, easy.

---

Now the second thing that is happening, in your other examples, is that reference variables *point to objects*. That is, they are essentially primitive integer variables that hold the memory address of an object. They follow the same rules as primitive types above! Before we look at the rest of your examples, consider the following:

```
int array[] = new int[] { 100, 200, 300 };

int example () {
    int index = 1;
    try {
       return index;
    } finally {
       array[index] = 500;
       index = 2;
    }
}
```

This method returns 1, not 2 (for reasons explained above). The finally block also modifies `array[1]`. So what, then, does `value` contain after the following:

```
int index = example();
int value = array[index];
```

It's 500, of course. We can see this without much explanation being required. The `example` method returns an index into an array. The `finally` block modifies the data in the array. When we look at the data at that index later, we see it contains 500, because the `finally` block set it to 500. *But changing the data in the array is unrelated to the fact that the returned index is still 1.*

*This is exactly the same as returning a reference.* Think of a reference variable as a primitive integer that is essentially an index into a large array of memory (the heap). Modifying the object that a reference points to is like modifying data in that array. Now, the rest of the examples should make more sense.

So let's look at your first example:

```
protected StringBuilder setOne(){
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
    try{
        builder.append("Cool"); // [1]
        return builder.append("Return"); // [2]
    }finally{
        builder.append("+1"); //[3]
    }
}
```

In your question, you've stated that you are confused because this method returns "CoolReturn+1". However, this statement fundamentally doesn't make much sense! This method is *not* returning "CoolReturn+1". This method is returning a reference to a `StringBuilder` that happens to contain the data, "CoolReturn+1".

In this example, first line [1] is evaluated. Then line [2] is evaluated, and `.append("Return")` is executed. Then the `finally` block happens, and line [3] is evaluated. Then, since you've already told the method to return a reference to that `StringBuilder`, that reference is returned. The `StringBuilder` pointed to by the returned reference has been modified by `finally`, and that's OK. That does not affect the *value* returned by the method, which is simply a reference to an object (i.e. the "index" into that big array of memory I described earlier).

Ok, so let's look at your second example:

```
protected String setOne(){
    String str = "fail";
    try{
        str = "success";
        return str;
    }finally{
        str = str + "fail";
    }
}
```

This returns a reference to a `String` that contains the data, "success". Why? For all the reasons already described above. This line:

```
str = str + "fail";
```

Simply creates a new `String` object that is the concatenation of the two strings, and then assigns `str` a reference to that new object. However, as with the primitive `int` example, we've already told the function to return a reference to the "success" `String`, and we cannot change that no matter what we do!

---

Conclusion:

You can come up with an infinite number of examples, but the rules will always be the same: The return value is evaluated in the `return` statement, and the value cannot be changed later. Reference variables are simply values that hold memory addresses of objects, and that memory address value cannot be changed, even though the object at that address can certainly be modified by `finally`.

Note also that immutability is irrelevant to the general concept here. In the `String` example it is a bit of a red herring. Keep in mind that even if `String`s *were* mutable, we would never expect a binary `+` operator to modify the fields of its left operand (e.g. even if strings had, say, an `append()` method, `a = a + b` would not be expected to modify any fields of `a`, it would be expected to return a new object then store a reference to that in `a`, leaving the original a untouched). One source of confusion here is that Java allows `+` on String as a convenience; no other objects directly support operators like that (not counting automatic unboxing of primitive wrappers).

I did mark this question as a duplicate of [Why does changing the returned variable in a finally block not change the return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030858/why-does-changing-the-returned-variable-in-a-finally-block-not-change-the-return). I believe that, once you have your head wrapped around the concepts here, it will be clear that the question and answer there are essentially the same as the question and answers here.

Comment: This is technically correct, but doesn't really explain what happened...

Comment: Okay, then it is also applicable in 1st case also. Then it is not returning just `CoolReturn`?

Comment: -1, the first example does exactly what you just described with an unexpected result.

Comment: @JustinC No it doesn't. The value to be returned is a *reference* to a `StringBuilder`. That value remains constant. That doesn't mean the object pointed to by that reference can't be modified.

Comment: @Vishrant No. It's not returning a string at all. It's returning a reference to a `StringBuilder`. The reference returned is the same one that `return` specified. Modifying the object that reference points to has no impact on the actual reference value that is returned; it's still the same `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Jason, I would put all that in your answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just did.

Comment: Now, you deserve _all_ the upvotes.

Comment: +1 because absolutely correct. Only addition for the kings of nerds with a decent jdk: Have a look at the bytecode.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks. I guess it wasn't a great answer in its original form. I took it for granted that "references" were understood. I've added some explanation.

Comment: @JasonC I think your array example is incorrect we can change values at array index in finally block and then we can access the same in returned method. int[] setOne() { int arr[] = new int[5]; try { arr[0] = 10; arr[1] = 30; return arr; } finally { arr[1] = 20; }} . `Call like` setOne()[1]

Comment: @Vishrant Note that I said returning an *index*. The example in your comment returns a reference to an entire array. So, I'm not quite sure I understand what you are trying to say with this example; it does not seem to be related to your original examples or to my array example, and it is not an example of the `finally` block modifying the value that is returned.

Answer (score 1):

In the first non-working example, you do

```
return str;
```

then in the finally block you do

```
str = str + "fail";
```

The code in the finally block is equivalent to

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
temp.apend(str);
temp.append("fail");
str = temp.toString();
```

This doesn't affect the original reference to str that was returned.  The original value of str was saved to be returned, and then you changed str to point somewhere else.  That new reference does not get returned.

Answer (score 0):

You get `success` in the second example because the `StringBuilder` class does NOT create a new instance of the string when using the methods. In the second example, you are returning an instance of `str` that contains "success", but then in the finally clause, you are creating a new instance that contains `successfail`.

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers (so far), are correct, but all struggle to say what really is happening.

When you write `return x;` you are assigning an invisible variable that holds the value that the function will return after the finally block has been executed.  That variable variously holds a StringBuilder reference, or a String reference, or a primitive int value in your three examples.

When you write `finally { x = ...; }`, you are assigning a new value to the local variable, x.  This does not have any effect on the hidden variable that holds the return value.  In your second example, the assignment in the finally statement constructs a new String instance, and stores a reference to it in the local var, str.  But, the hidden variable still references the original String instance.

When you write `finally { builder.append(...); }`, something different happens.  There, you are not assigning any variable at all.  In that case, both `builder` and the hidden variable both refer to the same StringBuilder instance, and the `append(...)` call modifies that instance.