# why does value of variable updated by the finally block not get returned by the try block?

Tags: java, return, try-catch, finally

For below program i am getting output as below. 
**Output:** 
In try 
In finally 
3

Why it is not returning 7 instead of 3?

```
public class MyFirstJavaProgram {
   public static void main(String []args) {
      int c = 10;
      c=get(c);
      System.out.println(c);
   }
   public static int get(int c){
       try{
       c=3;
       System.out.println("In try");
      return c;
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           c=5;
           System.out.println("In catch");
           return c;
       }
       finally{
           c=7;
           System.out.println("In finally");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: finnally bloc  is not always executed, for more infos looks at this repsonse 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-a-finally-block-always-get-executed-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does changing the returned variable in a finally block not change the return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030858/why-does-changing-the-returned-variable-in-a-finally-block-not-change-the-return)

Comment: You're not "returning a variable", you are returning a value. The return value has been determined to be 3 by evaluating the expression `c`.  Subsequent changes to `c` have nothing to do with the prior result.