# Why does method return `true` if I change the value of `r` to `false` in finally?

Tags: java

Why does method return `true` if I change the value of `r` to `false` in finally?

```
boolean myMethod() {
    boolean r = true;
    try {
        throw new Exception("");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return r;
    } finally {
        //System.out.println("executing finally");// will print if we uncomment this line
        r = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys, updated my question and code

Comment: What compile time errors? I'm compiling it just fine in Java 7.

Comment: @Makoto well, i guess it compiles now, after OP has updated his code.

Comment: @Makoto Did you check this version https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30265772/1?

Comment: Why would I check past revisions?  Comments are temporal enough to exist at the moment that I read them.

Comment: Why do you expect it to return false?

Comment: I don't know who reopened this, but now that the code is fixed, that Q/A was the obvious duplicate.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I reopened to change duplicate target. IMO new one is more precise. First duplicate looks like suggestion that `finally` block didn't execute, which was not true.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708834/does-return-happen-after-finally

Comment: @DrewKennedy You either misread answer in duplicate question, or you read old duplicate. `finally` will be executed, but changing value of `q` reference doesn't mean that it will also change value cached by `return` before it moved to `finally` block. To change such value we would need to add new `return` inside `finally` block like `finally { r = false; return r; }`.

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah I just tested it and, while knowing the finally block always executes, I actually thought it would be disregarded. I guess the finally block still executes as always, but the value change is disregarded. Kinda cool, actually.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Yes that is one of many Java gotchas.