# will this finally block execute?

Tags: java, finally

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, does return trump finally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally)

I came across a java code snippet in a dao implementation .It returns a List as shown below.

After the  'return' statement is executed,the finally block tries to close the session.Will this work? or will the session remain open?

thanks

mark

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
...
public List<Item> findItems(String name) {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    try{
        Criteria cri = session.createCriteria(Item.class);
        return (List<Item>) cri.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name)).list();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: Add a `System.out.println("Elvis was here");` in the finally block, and you will see...

Answer (score 5):

The only time a finally block will not be executed is if you terminate your program such as System.exit(0) or force quit etc. So the answer is: Yes, your session will be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Read up on [The finally Block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html), and yes, the finally block will be executed after the `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `finally` blocks will always execute (*).

The `finally` block will execute "after" the `return` in the sense that the return value will be computed and remembered *before* the `finally` block is executed.

(*) caveat: unless something causes the JVM to end operation alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the finally block will be executed after the `return` statement but before the value is fully returned to the method.