# Accessing variable inside try catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I keep getting a compile error on the return menuFont line it says there is no variable menuFont. Could someone please tell how to fix this.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


public class loadFiles {
Font getFont(){
            try {
                Font menuFont = Font.createFont( Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("font.ttf"));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Cant find file.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FontFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong file type.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unknown error.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return menuFont;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The basic problem with your code is that the Font object is only in scope for the duration of the try block, so it's no longer available in your return statement at the end of the method. Two options:

Move the variable declaration outside the try block:

```
Font menuFont = null;
try {
    menuFont = Font.createFont(...);
}
catch (...) {

}
return menuFont;
```

Or, do `return Font.creatFont(...)` inside the try, thus avoiding the need for the variable in the first place (and, obviously, `return null` at the end of the method).

Comment: running this in sonarQube show this can throw a nullpointerexception

Answer (score 4):

The `menuFont` variable scope is inside the try block. Move the variable outside of it instead. 
Something like:

```
  Font getFont(){
        Font menuFont = null; 
        try {
            menuFont = Font.createFont( Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("font.ttf"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cant find file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong file type.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unknown error.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return menuFont;
  }
```

Be aware that in case of an exception, this method will return a `null` font.

Answer (score 3):

you must declare the variable menuFont outside...

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class loadFiles {
    Font getFont(){
        Font menuFont = null;
        try {
            menuFont = Font.createFont( Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("font.ttf"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cant find file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong file type.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unknown error.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return menuFont;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because menuFont doesn't exist within the scope of the getFont method.  Variables defined outside your current scope/block (pair of curly braces) are available, whereas ones defined in a nested block are not.  You can correct this one of two ways:

- Move the declaration of `menuFont` to above the `try` (within the scope of the `getFont`).  Because you're anticipating an exception in Font.createFont, leave that code inside the `try` block.
- Move the `return` statement to inside the `try` block.

Please see the answers to [Does finally always execute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally/65949#65949) for more subtleties about try/catch/finally.

Answer (score 2):

`menuFont` doesn't exist outside of the `try` block, which is what your compiler's trying to tell you. Instead, declare it before the `try` block and then try and assign a value to it inside the `try` block:

```
Font menuFont;

try {
   Font menuFont = ...
}
...

return menuFont;
```

Answer (score 2):

That because of the scope of your `menuFont` variable. You declare it inside the `try`, which means it will not be accessible from anywhere but inside those two braces. If you want to be able to access it in the `catch`, or anywhere outside the `try`, change your code to something as follows:

```
Font menuFont = null;
try {
    menuFont = Font.createFont( Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("font.ttf"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // you can access menuFont here (too)
}
//...
return menuFont; // <-- note: can be null here
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would do the following:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


public class loadFiles {
Font menuFont = null;
Font getFont(){
            try {
                menuFont = Font.createFont( Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("font.ttf"));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Cant find file.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FontFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong file type.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unknown error.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return menuFont; // could potentially be null!
}
```

And check for `null` wherever you call this method.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it outside the `try` block.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.4.2