# how to use the variables declared in try block?

Tags: java, variables, exception, try-catch

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    int a=sc.nextInt();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("enter integer only");
}
```

in the above code, how to access the int variable `a` outside of the `try` block in the program?

Comment: Declare the variable outside the try block and assign it inside

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551020/accessing-variable-inside-try-catch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing variable inside try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551020/accessing-variable-inside-try-catch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared inside a block (a `try` block in this case) are only accessible within that scope. If you want to use them outside that scope, you should **declare** them outsie of it:

```
int a; // Declared outside the scope
try {
    a=sc.nextInt();
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("enter integer only");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best would probably be to use a `while-true-loop` and read a whole `String`, and then try to parse that, and if it doesn't fail assign it to the variable `a` declared outside of the loop and try block:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a;
while(true){
    String potentialInt = sc.nextLine();
    try{
        a = Integer.parseInt(potentialInt);
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("Enter integers only");
    }
}
```