# what happens if both try and finally returns boolean in a method

Tags: java

I have a class-
public class Check {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Check().isRight());
}


public boolean isRight(){
    try{
        return true;
    }finally{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method isRight has return true and false in finally clause , and finally it returns me false as finally clause will surely be called, so whats actually happening the data inside try. 
I need to know the logical reason behind the output , I read but couldn;t understand properly.

Comment: Why would you write such a messy code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange finally behaviour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187148/strange-finally-behaviour) or [Java-try-finally-return-design-question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185340/java-try-finally-return-design-question)

Comment: i just want this info for learning . nothing about exact code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java

Comment: @bunta Compiler throws a warning about the finally block not terminating properly, so even the compiler thinks this code is messsy.

Comment: quite an odd question, all basic logic would tell you the answer is that finally is called..finally..so it returns..false..

Comment: OK, I don't know why this question still isn't closed. It is obviously duplicate...

Comment: At call-stack level, the value of the frame that contains the return value is first populated by the code in the try block. But eventually as control goes to finally, the code in finally block overwrites the return frame. Hence, the return data produced by code inside the try block is overwritten by the code inside finally block. For better understanding read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`finally` will not be called only if you use `System.exit()` or JVM craches.

In all other cases, `finally` will be called, so `false` will be returned. How?

When the `return` in `try` is reached, the control transfers to `finally`, there you `return false`.. Simple.

Go through the [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) to better understand that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code always returns false because the `finally` block is **always** executed after `try-catch` statements are executed no matter what unless the JVM crashes or on `System.exit()` as others have already mentioned.

So, when the `try` block reaches the  `return true;` statement the control is passed  however to the `finally` block and it returns false (over-riding the previous true value).

Answer (score 0):

`false` will be returned there. That's the idea of finally - it gets the last say on things. *`finally`* will be invoked and will return false as mentioned in your code.