# Does finally always get called?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, does return trump finally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally)

What does this function return?

```
public int wasExceptionThrown() {
   try {
     if(1==1)
        throw new RuntimeException();
     return 1;
   } catch(Exception e) {
     return 2;
   } finally {
     return 3;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? Hopefully you have a computer with java.

Comment: to answer the title, yes.

Comment: To begin with, that function doesn't compile, because `return 1` is unreachable.

Comment: sorry, i made some edits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you call `System.exit(0);` then `finally` blocks are not called as the thread is shutdown immediately.  In all other cases `finally` is called when the block exits (assuming it does)

Comment: or if JVM crashes first before executing finally

Comment: @NirmitSrivastava Yes, a signal crash rather than an error thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Finally called `before` return.

The only time finally won't be called is if you call System.exit() or if the JVM crashes first.