# Sqlite verify if value of column exists

Tags: android, sqlite, select, cursor

i'm wondering if this method is right to verify if the value of _username already exists in the column "username"

```
public boolean verification(String _username) throws SQLException{
    Cursor c = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+KEY_USERNAME+"="+_username, null);
    if (c!=null)
        return true; // return true if the value of _username already exists
    return false; // Return false if _username doesn't match with any value of the columns "Username"
}
```

Is there a better way to do the same thing, i'm really not sure about this, it seemed right for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do the same thing, i'm really not sure about
>   this, it seemed right for me. Thanks.

In the terms of security and purity yes, for sure.

```
public boolean verification(String _username) throws SQLException {
    int count = -1;
    Cursor c = null; 
    try {
       String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " 
                   + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME + " = ?"
       c = dataBase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {_username});
       if (c.moveToFirst()) {
          count = c.getInt(0);
       }
       return count > 0;
    }
    finally {
       if (c != null) {
          c.close();
       }
    }
}
```

I recommend you to an usage of **`?`** that is called **placeholder**. Each placeholder will be replaced with value from string array in the same order. This is called also parametrized statement as a defence agains SQL injection. When your work with Cursor is finished, release it.

Comment: The notion that [`finally` trumps `return`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/65035/1267661) doesn't come naturally to me.

Comment: @Sam sam, i like using try-catch block, finally block will be applied always and it has many advantages. I know that i don't catching anything but user can for example in try block perform division by zero and problem is here...

Comment: Thank you ! I did that, but instead of return count>0; i did count=>0; 
Did you just forget it ? if not, can you please explain me why count ==0 must return false ? c.getInt(0) can return 0 no ? Thank you anyway, your answer was really helpful

Comment: @R00t if your username exists in db so count is 1. if not, count is 0. so verification will be successful if count > 0(so if count is 1) it returns true.

Comment: @Sajmon Ahh yes, i forgot that ID autoincrement begin with the value 1 . Thanks dude :)

Answer (score 6):

[Beware](http://xkcd.com/327/) of [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)! You should always use a parameterized query:

```
Cursor c = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT 1 FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+KEY_USERNAME+"=?", new String[] {_username});
```

(Honestly I'm not sure how your first query didn't throw an exception since you forgot to wrap the string in quotes...)

Also `rawQuery()` will always return a Cursor, you must check if the Cursor is *empty*, not `null`.

---

As for "the best" approach, this works fine, but I recommend closing the Cursor to free up resources. All together:

```
public boolean verification(String _username) {
    Cursor c = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT 1 FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+KEY_USERNAME+"=?", new String[] {_username});
    boolean exists = c.moveToFirst();
    c.close();
    return exists;
}
```

Comment: @Sajmon : answer quality is important instead of answering any question first

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK you right man i added to previous comment smiles :))

Comment: Thank you ! I thought rawQuerry would return 'null', but it works when  i verified if the cursor is empty. Sorry i can't mark this comment as the answer even if this is the answer, i marked the first one that i saw. But you were really helpful, thank you !