# When finally is executed?

Tags: java, android, try-catch

I have this java code with nested try:

```
try
{   
    try
    {
        [ ... ]
    {
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        showLogMessage(ex);
        return;
    }

    while (condition == true)
    {
        try
        {
            [ ... ]
        {
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            showLogMessage(ex);
            continue;
        }

        [ ... ]
    }
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    showLogMessage(e);
}
finally
{
    doSomeThingVeryImportant();
}
```

I want to know if `finally` is always executed when I get an exception. I ask this because catch blocks have `return` or `continue` statements.

**When is `doSomeThingVeryImportant()` executed? When I get an `Exception` on when I get a `NumberFormatException`?**

I only want if after any catch block is executed, the finally block is executed also.

Comment: out of curiosity and extending of the question: is finally executed even after an `exit` statement?

Comment: You'd have run your code and seen for yourself, if it executes or not, when you get an exception! I really doubt if anything which is not present in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) has been posted in any of the answers below!

Comment: Please stop down voting. It isn't a duplicate question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`The finally block always executes when the try block exits` ([click](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)).

Comment: I have changed the question.

Comment: It won't always. If a System.exit() calls, finally won't get executed.

Comment: @tostao I cannot agree with you. What do you think about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java/22583252#22583252

Comment: This is correct - why is it voted down? Crashing, exiting on purpose, etc. do not count as exceptions in this case as the question obviously implies what happens when the code/program continues execution not when the computer crashes, there is a power failure or the user exits in purpose - sure then nothing executes.

Answer (score 20):

The finally block, if used, is placed after a try block and the catch blocks that follow it. The finally block contains code that will be run whether or not an exception is thrown in a try block. The general syntax looks like this:

```
public void someMethod{
   Try {
   // some code
   }

   Catch(Exception x) {
   // some code
   }

   Catch(ExceptionClass y) {
   // some code
   }

   Finally{
   //this code will be executed whether or not an exception 
   //is thrown or caught
   }
}
```

There are 4 potential scenarios here:

1. The try block runs to the end, and no exception is 
   thrown.  In this scenario, the finally block will be 
   executed after the try block.
2. An exception is thrown in the try block, which is
   then caught in one of the catch blocks.  In this scenario, 
   the finally block will execute right after the catch block 
   executes.
3. An exception is thrown in the try block and there's 
   no matching catch block in the method that can catch 
   the exception.  In this scenario, the call to the method 
   ends, and the exception object   is thrown to the enclosing 
   method - as in the method in which the   try-catch-finally
   blocks reside.  But, before the method ends, the finally 
   block is executed.
4. Before the try block runs to completion it returns to 
   wherever the method was invoked.  But, before it returns 
   to the invoking method, the code in the finally block is still 
   executed.  So, remember that the code in the finally  block 
   willstill be executed even if there is a return 
   statement somewhere in the try block.

**Update:** Finally ALWAYS gets executed, no matter what happens in the try or catch block (fail, return, exception, finish etc.).

Comment: I only want if after any catch block is executed, the finally block is executed also.

Comment: @VansFannel Yes it will execute, no matter if catch is being called or not

Comment: Sorry, but I don't asking that. I ask if after a catch block with a return statement inside, the finally method is executed or if return without execution. And there are catch block with a continue inside. I want to know if after continue call, finally is executed.

Comment: Yes then also it will be called Because that's the whole point of a finally block. See my update

Comment: this should be the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

```
The finally block always executes when the try block exits. 
This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs
```

Taken from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Further, the page explains that the finally block `may not` be executed if the JVM exists while the try or catch code is being executed, or if the thread executing the try/catch is interrupted or killed.

So unless you may kill the JVM or the try/catch is beeing executed in a thread, the finally block will always be executed

Comment: I have changed the question.

Comment: The finally block will be run even if there is an exception and if you return/break/Continue in a catch block. The only time it may not be run is if the JVM dies or the thread executing the try/catch is killed or interrupted. So the answer to your question is YES

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Finally always executes. With exception and with NO exception.

It's the way to be sure some portion of code get **always** executed.

Used for example, to dispose objects, to close opened server connections and that kind of stuff.

Check this link from oracle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: What if there is a return statement in the catch?

Comment: I have changed the question.

Comment: @Marc Finally block will be executed even if there is a return in the catch

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `finally` blocks are always executed.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: Yes, since it's in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; or, at least, as close to "always" as possible. (So, even if you have a `return` or another `throw`.)

If your process is killed, or your program gets stuck in a deadlock or infinite loop, or your device is struck by a meteor, then program flow will not reach the `finally` block.

Comment: I have changed the question.

Answer (score 2):

Say your code block is something like this  :

```
 try
    {   
        try
        {
            System.out.println("first try block");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("first cathc block");
            return;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
               System.out.println("second try block...");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("second catch block");
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println("end of loop");
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("last catch block");
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("finally block");
    }
```

If you run this then the output that you will get is :

```
first try block
second try block...
end of loop
finally block
```

So `finally block` gets executed anyway.

Comment: I have changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes finally always gets executed and its because one can **program to close/handle resources** in case of exceptions or no exception without fail.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

---

Update to answer the question in comment about `System.exit()`

The finally block will not execute in case of `System.exit()` unless it fails with some `SecurityException`.

---

Update after question changed. No matter what the exception is finally block will always execute.

If its `Exception` then your catch block will not execute as it catches only `NumberFormatException`

Comment: I have updated the question: Is doSomeThingVeryImportant() always executed when I get an exception?

Comment: Yes in your case doSomeThingVeryImportant() will always execute.

Comment: Actually this is not true. The finally block may not be executed if the JVM is killed or the try/catch is beeing executed in a thread that may be interrupted or killed

Comment: I have changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, finally blocks are always executed.**  But terms and conditions apply .

Untill unless you call **System.exit();**

Comment: I have changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, finally won't get execute always. There are two situations where Finally won't get execute.

> **Note**: If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.

[java reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

For your question, if these two things are not there, whatever inside your finally will get executed, that's sure.

Comment: I have changed the question.

Comment: @VansFannel Whether you get a exception or not, finally will get executed always. If there is a finally associated with try, if a exception occurs or not, finally will surely be executed