# java finally block and checked exceptions

Tags: java, exception

If I have the following code

```
try {
    //some stuff here
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new CustomException();
} finally {
    finalize();
}
```

where `CustomException` is a checked exception,

Will the `finally` block be called in the event of an `Exception`?

EDIT:
Perhaps "finalize()" was a poor choice of wording. I DID NOT mean the finalize() method of Object. I just meant that there was cleanup code that needed done. Apologies for that.

Comment: `finally` block is **always** called.

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to either catch the `CustomException` or declare it as being thrown from the enclosing method.

Comment: There was a much easier way for you to find out.

Comment: @SJuan76 Almost always. Java could crash before it's called...

Comment: @Shaded Or someone could pull the plug from the computer, or a volcano might erupt and bury the computer under lava before the statement is reached etc...

Comment: @Jesper Exactly! At least I'm not alone in believing volcanos are out to get me.

Comment: Though you should never invoke `finalize()` on an object anyway. In most cases you don’t need a `finalize()` method but if you need it, it will be called by the JVM automatically. Invoking it by yourself means risking `finalize()` beeing called twice, once by your code and once by the JVM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does finally always execute in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Finally is ALWAYS called, regardless of exceptions and even return statements.

I recommend checking the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) on it.

Answer (score 1):

It will **always** be called in the event of an exception.  For that matter, it will always be called, period.  That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

`finally` is always called(even if you call `return;`), unless you call

```
System.exit();
```

in `try` or `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

finally block is called in each cases.

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block is always executed. It is designed so that you can perform important operations regardless of any exceptions being thrown, for example close streams.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `finally` is ALWAYS executed, no matter what happens, short of the JVM dying before your code is reached.  It will even get called in this case:

```
public boolean doSomething() throws Exception{
    boolean iDidIt = true;
    try{
        //attempt to do it
        return iDidIt;
    catch(Exception e){
        iDidIt = false;
        return iDidIt;
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Did something get done? "+iDidIt);
    }
}
```

The print statement will get printed no matter what.