# try{} finally{} construct with return values

Tags: java

I was wondering why the following code would be accepted by the Java compiler:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String ... args){
        System.out.println("a() = " + a());
    }

    public static String a (){
        try {
            return "a";
        }catch(Throwable t){
        }finally{
            return "b";
        }
    }
}
```

This can and should not work. The java specification states the `finally` block will **always** be executed, but at the same time the return value has already been specified. So either you cannot execute the `return "b"` statement, because you have exited at `return "a"`, which would be incorrect.

However, the other option is that you execute the `return "b"` statement, and thereby totally disregarding the `return "a"` statement...

I would say that both are wrong, and I would expect that this does not compile. However it compiles and runs fine. I will leave the answer as a nice exercise to the reader ;).

Basically my question is: *Besides being bad practice, would this be considered a Java bug, or does this have other wonderful uses other than obfuscation?*

### Edit:

The question is not so much if it is a bug, that has been answered, but does it have nice use cases?

Comment: The question is one of the most interesting questions I have read this week. However, to my understanding, the `try` block can never throw an exception.

Comment: Very unexpected output !!

Comment: Question has *a lot* of duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185340/java-try-finally-return-design-question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899155/try-catch-block-return-with-finally-clause-in-java ...

Comment: A finally block has the right to override any return value.
So your code should return "b".

Comment: @Hichamov What is unexpected in this output?

Comment: @Codor you are correct. I've just tried this and IntelliJ reports "'finally' block can not complete normally" and "'return' inside 'finally' block: While occasionally intended, such return statements may mask exceptions thrown, and tremendously complicate debugging."

Comment: @Marv actually, my intellij doesn't warn me at all.

Comment: I think it is interesting question, i never heard about anyone use return in finally block at all. Personally i want consider this as bug, more as bad practice. Other thing is, as i remember finally block is not always executed, if i remeber if you call `System.exit` it want be executed

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer most of your cited duplicates do not mention return values

Comment: 1) "most of" suffices for duplicates. 2) They all explain the semantics. No need for this question.

Comment: @Codor interesting. I get [three warnings](http://i.imgur.com/cIhDmru.png), maybe you have disabled some that are usually enabled or the other way around...

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer please cite me a question which asks for a use case :-). Modified my question to emphasise that part.

Comment: @Yuri - Asking for a use-case makes this off-topic, as it tends to attract opinionated answers, which is a different reason to close. This is a Q&A website - there should be definitive answers to questions, not opinions. I'm voting to leave this closed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Everything works exactly as expected, no bugs here. When you have doubts, the JLS is your savior:

[**JLS - 14.20.2. Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2):

> If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly for any other
>   reason R, then the `finally` block is executed, and then there is a
>   choice:
>
> - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement
>     completes  abruptly for reason R.
> - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try 
>     statement  completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is
>     discarded).

It *overrides* the value in the `try` block.

`return` inside `finally` discards all exceptions that can be thrown in `try` clause.

Comment: Ok, so no bug. Thanks, but what about a **use-case**

Comment: @Yuri I actually cannot think of a situation where this is useful.

Comment: So in that case it would just be a weird design decision :-)

Comment: @Yuri Think of a situation where you have `something = null; try { run = tryThis(); } finally { cleanThings(); return something; }` It might be useful if you want to return `null` as a default value if something bad happened..

Comment: @MarounMaroun If something bad happend? It would always return null.

Comment: @Tom You're right, but it won't cleanup things.. Maybe I'm over trying to find useful case ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Well, a use case is, that a return in `finally` would always return a specific value, no matter if an exception occurred or not. So you don't have to write the return statement in the `try`and every `catch` block. But I don't think that this was the main reason for this design decision.

Comment: think about this one: `int a=3; try{ return ++a; }catch(..){}finally{ return ++a; }`, isn't this awesome?

Comment: @Yuri Why would this be useful?

Comment: @Yuri what is awesome about that?

Comment: @Tom it returns 5 ;)

Comment: @Yuri `int a=3; return a+=2;` does that too.

Comment: @Tom you're not very good at code obfuscation, are you? ;-). Just kidding, I was being somewhat sarcastic as to the utter uselessness of this construction :-).