# Finally always executed before method is finished?

Tags: java, try-catch

I stepped upon a case where I want to write my code like this:

```
try {  
    something();  
    return success;  
}  
catch (Exception e) {   
    return failure;  
}  
finally {  
    System.out.println("i don't know if this will get printed out.");
}
```

(from [Does finally always execute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java))

My question is:

Is `finally` always executed before the method is finished or does it run in an extra `thread` (because the method is already finished with the object's return)?

In other words: Is it guaranteed that finally is executed before main method is continued?

Comment: Imagine it like this: The compiler puts the code from the finally block before every return (and every other path of exiting from that method, like an exception).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything happens in the same thread, only the ordering is different from the program order:

1. `return x` executes only in the part where `x` is determined as the return value;
2. `finally` block executes;
3. the value remembered in 1. is returned from the method—*unless* the `finally` block executes a `return` statement of its own/throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is, It's Part of method.

Even after the `return` the [`finally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) executes.

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits.

Why ?

> This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs.

And to clarify your doubt. let's check the below code(**For testing only, Not a good practice**).

```
ry {  
    something();  
    return success;  
}  
catch (Exception e) {   
    return failure;  
}  
finally {  
    System.out.println("i don't know if this will get printed out.");
    return success;  //method returns this 
}
```

Now the method returns the value in finally

Comment: That was not my question.

Comment: @Coretek updated my post. Let me know if you need some more clarification

Answer (score 0):

if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.

Comment: And how do you kill the thread (without writing code inside the try/catch block which would result in the finally block being called) and keep the application running?

Comment: Main thread may kill its children incase it goes into some error.

Comment: There is no inherent parent-child relationship like this in Java threads. You would have to code this, and then again finally would apply if you set the block correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For `try-finally` or `try-catch-finally`: A finally clause ensures that the finally block is executed after the try block and any catch block that might be executed, no matter how control leaves the try block or catch block.

However, In terms of returning a value with a `return` statement:

- The `try` and `catch` block's returning value with `return` statement is remembered.
- If the `finally` block doesn't have a return statement, After executing the `finally` block:

  1. If no exception happened and(or) wasn't caught by the `catch` block:   remembered returning value of the `try` block is returned.
  2. else, remembered returning value of the `catch` block is returned.
- else, it will return value with the finally block's  return statement forgetting about the `try` and(or) `catch` block's  return.

  ```
   public static Integer returnData()
   {
      Integer x = null;

      try{
        System.out.println("try the x: "+x);
        return x;
      }
      finally
      {
         x = 5;  // here i am assigning 5
         System.out.println("finally is printed with: "+x);  // printing 5
         return x;
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Printing the return value in main: "+returnData());
        // printed 5 according to the assignment in finally block
    }
  ```

Even if the above function should return `null` in the `try` block, you will see that running the above example will print:

```
try the x: null
Hi finally is printed with: 5
Printing the return value in main: 5
```

Now, if you remove the return statement from `finally` block, you will see the following output:

```
try the x: null
finally is printed with: 5
Printing the return value in main: null
```

As `null` was remembered as the returning value from the `try` block.

check out the [jls: 14.20.2. **Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) For more details.