# Closed Connection: next in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have ResultSet Methods which I am closing the Connection in a finallly Block:

```
 public static ResultSet countdrcountcr(String vforacid) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {

            conn = db.getDbConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT NVL (SUM (DECODE (part_tran_type, 'D', 1, 0)), 0), "
                    + " NVL (SUM (DECODE (part_tran_type, 'C', 1, 0)), 0) "
                    + " FROM tbaadm.htd WHERE acid IN (SELECT acid "
                    + " FROM tbaadm.gam WHERE foracid = '" + vforacid + "') "
                    + " AND tran_date >= '22-NOV-2013'  AND tran_date <= '30-NOV-2013' "
                    + " AND pstd_flg = 'Y' AND del_flg != 'Y'";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            return rs;
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the error :

**edit The whole ErrorTrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection: next
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:181)
at statement.Statement.main(Statement.java:34)
Java Result: 1
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: Can you point the line that the error occurs and put your stacktrace on your question please.

Comment: You're closing the connection but still using the resultset.

Comment: Yes I returned the value before Closing. The error is occuring When I try to call this ResultSet `while(rs1.next())`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're returning a `ResultSet` for future use but after using it you're closing the connection, so you have no way to retrieve the data since the resource is already closed. Note that `finally` is always called, even if you return something in the `try` or `catch` code block, refer to [Does finally always execute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035/1065197)

In detail, this is the problem:

1. Open the connection
2. Prepare a statement
3. Get the result set
4. Return the result set
5. Close the connection (that may close the associated resources i.e. it may close the `PreparedStatement` and the `ResultSet` associated with the current `Connection`) because, as noted in the link before, `finally` block is **always** executed at least that the JVM crashes or you manually finish the application using `System.exit`.
6. Using a closed `ResultSet`. It is closed due to the previous step.

A possible solution would be that your `countdrcountcr` method and all other methods that return a `ResultSet` receive the `Connection` as parameter, so the method that calls it will handle the connection opening and closing. Also, take note that you should not use `static` methods to handle your database operations if you're working in a multi threaded environment e.g. a web application.

Comment: Could you please explain why so, if a return value is set before the con.close(); I mean the control flow Execute all the code=>rs is already refereed to the set of rows=> return this value => and close the connection . why do con need the connection still if the value is already refered?

Answer (score 1):

I think your query is taking a long time to execute and getting terminated by the driver/tomcat level.

Check you application context xml file for parameter ***removeAbandonedTimeout*** value.

**removeAbandonedTimeout**=300

means, if any query running for more than 300 seconds will be close by the JDBC driver. This is done to avoid connection pool "leak". To fix this you can set the value with some higher number.

More info about this param and other related parameters can be found [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Preventing_database_connection_pool_leaks)

Comment: This answer solved my issue. We were using tomcat pool and the driver was closing the connection if it exceeded the removeAbondonedTimeout

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the underlying `Connection` in your finally block... You're not closing the PreparedStatement (and you should, but you need to close that after you use your `ResultSet` too). use the finally block of the caller (where you open the `Connection`). Also, you might want to consider using [setFetchSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#setFetchSize%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot close a `Connection` then use the `ResultSet`.  You have to finish using the `ResultSet` first, then close the `Connection` sometime after.  The normal pattern is to finish your work with the `ResultSet` first, usually in a "Data Access Object", and return some encapsulated representation of the data as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Luiggi's answer is correct but it seems like what the OP didn't understand was why closing the connection prevented the ResultSet from working, since the code got the ResultSet before the connection closed.

There's a popular misunderstanding that a ResultSet must be some kind of data-holding object that you can use to pass stuff around in. It isn't. it's just a reference to a database cursor, it hasn't actually fetched the data for a row until you call `next()` on it. It needs a live connection in order to work. You need to unpack your results from the query into a collection (usually a list) before you close the connection.

BTW, don't add parameters to your SQL with string concatenation, it opens you up to SQL injection (and also handles quoting the parameters is a pain). You can add `?` to your SQL and add values for the parameters by calling methods on the preparedStatement.

If you use Spring JDBC it will handle all the tedious JDBC stuff for you (including closing everything that needs to be closed), and all you have to handle is implementing a RowMapper to describe how to move data from the ResultSet into the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If u tryied to close the connection inside the while block that time also u can get this kind of exception...so close the connection after the while block

```
package com.literals;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DataBaseDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("driver is loading...........");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mytest","SYSTEM","murali");
            System.out.println("connection is established");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("statement is created");

            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from student");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"          "+rs.getInt(2)+"          "+rs.getString(3)+"");
                con.close();

            }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }





    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like say above: Also, take note that you should not use static methods to handle your database operations if you're working in a multi threaded environment e.g. a web application.

That really help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where my connection was being closed inside a `while` loop, so the condition could not be checked in the next round. To fix, I placed `con.close();` outside the loop and this resolved the issue. Like this:

```
    while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("NAME");
    }
    con.close(); //placed outside the loop
}
```