# Passing ResultSet from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el, resultset

I want to pass result set from Servlet to JSP page and have its value there in my JSP page.

Here is the code of the Servlet:

```java
protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Data select = new Data(username,password);
    try {
        Boolean result = select.Select(username, password);
        if (result) {
            ResultSet rset=select.SelectAll(username,password);
            request.setAttribute("user",rset);
            getServletConfig().getServletContext()
                    .getRequestDispatcher("/dashboard.jsp")
                    .forward(request,response);

        } else
            out.print("Please check your username and password");        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.print("There seems to be a exception" + e);
    }
}
```

The two function called here returns `boolean` value and `ResultSet` values respectively
Select function returns `boolean` value where as SelectAll returns `ResultSet`.

My JSP code looks like this:

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
Username: <c:out value="$(user.username)"/> <br/>
Email:    <c:out value="$(user.email)"/>    <br/>
Contact:  <c:out value="$(user.contact)"/>  <br/>
```

Comment: so what error or exception you are facing?

Comment: Are you sure that the ResultSet class contains the username property ?!!

Comment: I wouldn't pass the result set directly to the JSP, instead I'd pull the information out of the result set and expose it in a proper DTO.

Comment: Dave is right, using resultsets like this is not a good idea, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/20497778/217324

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To proceed with the resultset initialize the object `User`, that should have getters and setters

```
ResultSet rset=select.SelectAll(username,password);
if (rset.next()){
  User user = new User();
  user.setUsername(rset.get("username"));
  user.setEmail(rset.get("email"));
  user.setContact(rset.get("contact"));
  request.setAttribute("user",user);
  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/dashboard.jsp")
                    .forward(request,response);
}
```

Comment: Username:$(user.username)
 Email:$(user.email)
 Contact:$(user.contact) this is output i get after making class and adding content of result set to it

Comment: Because braces is used for EL expressions ${user.email}.

Answer (score 2):

Do not pass `ResultSet`! Instead, follow [DAO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) pattern and create Java POJO class with fields that will reflect columns in your database. Extract data from `ResultSet` via `while` loop (`while(rs.next()) {...}`), assign values to your previously created instance of POJO class and add that instance to `List` (in case you want to pass multiple users). Return list (in case of multiple users) or just an instance (in case of single user).

Set list of objects as an attribute and iterate over it via `JSTL` `forEach` loop in your `JSP` (in case of multiple users).