# java.sql.sqlexception closed connection next

Tags: java, jdbc

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYvww.png)

> java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection: next
>
> at
>       oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>       at
>       oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
>       at
>       oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:181)
>       at
>       com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.next(NewProxyResultSet.java:2859)

**Code**

```
if (rs != null) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        resultset = Stmt.executeQuery();
        if (resultset.next()) {
            count += resultset.getLong(1);
            resultset.close();
            resultset = null;
        }
        Stmt.close();
        Stmt = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: why set resultset to null after closing it? post more code as this seems to be right. also your connection seems to be closed. did you ever open one?

Comment: Paste the error text, not an image.  I don't appreciate clicking on links that take me god knows where.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closed Connection: next in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497778/closed-connection-next-in-java)

Comment: Can you explain duplicate of Closed Connection @code

Comment: @XtremeBaumer for more code here it is  here rs and resulset both are diffrent    `if (rs != null) {
while (rs.next()) {
resultset = Stmt.executeQuery();
if (resultset.next()) {
       count += resultset.getLong(1);
       resultset.close();
       resultset = null;
      }
      Stmt.close();
      Stmt = null;
}`

Comment: @VishalMittal Please update your question with the code snippet. Also, please provide the code snippets where `rs` is being initialized and closed.

Comment: Please don't provide code and error dumps alone.  At least say a couple of sentences to describe your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error `java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection: next` indicates that the `resultSet` is already closed when it is being used. Avoid closing the `resultSet` until it is guaranteed that it will not be used by the downstream code.

Looking at your code snippet, it looks like you are closing the `Stmt` instance withing the while loop and going to use it in the next iteration of the loop. That could be another reason for your issue. In that case, creating a new instance of the `Stmt` instance withing the loop should solve.