# Finally block will be executed in case of OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, exception, out-of-memory, runtime-error, finally

Consider below code,

```
public class Test {

    public void abc() {
        try {
            throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().abc();
    }

}
```

Output :

```
Exception in thread "main" finally
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at Test.abc(Test.java:5)
    at Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

So, `finally` block is getting executed in the case, however above output is not fixed each time.

1. So the question is, Here we are throwing `OutOfMemoryError` and
   `finally` block is getting executed. Is this true for every case ?
2. If yes then `finally` block will be executed when `OutOfMemoryError`
   will be thrown in reality, means memory area expansion will be
   performed while execution and enough memory not available ?

Comment: That's right. And another `OutOfMemoryError` may be thrown inside the `finally` block which will supersede the other one.

Comment: In that case eclipse warning is : "finally block does not complete normally".

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar - that error appears s because you're explicitly throwing the exception. In the real world it just happens.

Comment: And to add to what @SotiriosDelimanolis said - if a second OOM -- or any other exception -- happens in the middle of your `finally`, it means that your `finally` won't be completely executed.

Comment: The output is not 'fixed' because the message `finally` gets written to standard output but the stacktrace gets written to standard error.  Try `System.err.println("finally")` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things will get interesting if you try to do something in the finally block requiring additional memory:

```
public class Finally {

    public void abc() {
        try {
            throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        } finally {
            byte[] b = new byte[1024*1024*1024];
            System.out.println("finally");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Finally().abc();
    }
}
```

Now when you execute the code (`java -Xmx20m Finally` for example), you can easily end up in a situation where your available heap has been exhausted to the extent where the `finally` block cannot fully complete, thus its execution cannot be guaranteed. So I would not recommend to rely on finally blocks in case of `OutOfMemoryErrors`.

Answer (score 2):

that's right like said  Sotirios Delimanolis

and more surprisingly  even if you put a return in your try block the finally will be executed

**From the doc :**

> "finaly block allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code
>   accidentally   bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting
>   cleanup code in a   finally block is always a good practice, even when
>   no exceptions are anticipated"

check this for more information http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: There is a [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/65035/1686291) on `return`. Please explain in context of `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Looks pretty explanatory. In case of OOM, the finally block __will be executed__.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta `"more surprisingly even if you put a return..."` It is not surprising at all...I know that already. I want to know behavior in context of `OutOfMemoryError` not in context of `return` statement.

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar I think OOM is no different from any other error/exception. The only way the finally block will __not__ execute is if you call [`System.exit()` or the whole JVM has already crashed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java), which in all fairness could happen when OOM happens on some platforms. However, I have seen JVMs resiliently surviving OOM, although they would behave unpredictably.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta What about `for(;;){}` ? (PS : I found this on same question you provided)

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar as somebody summarized on that thread, the finally will always be executed __after leaving the try block__. If you prevent your code from leaving the try block (as with an infinite loop) then there is no way __anything else__ will ever be executed. Unless of course an exception is thrown from within the loop, in which case it won't be infinite. The point here is that OOME is not "special" in any way.

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar why don't you write a small program to test the behavior yourself? Just start the JVM with a small amount of memory and allocate a lot of objects and see what happens. There's no point in continuing this conversation until you try it by yourself. And if you find any odd behavior please post it. It will be everybody's pleasure to figure out what is going on.