# Where's the "right place" to put return statement in try catch finally

Tags: java, return, try-catch

End of try block, or after all blocks?

I read a lot of answers on stack overflow about what will happen in each case. However, I could not find out which one is the commonly accepted "corrected" place to return.

```
Object o = null;
try {
  Connection c = getConnection();
  o = c.getThing();
  return o;
} catch (Exception e) {
  //handle exception
  return null;
} finally {
  c.close();
}
```

vs

```
Object o = null;
try {
  Connection c = getConnection();
  o = c.getThing();
} catch (Exception e) {
  //handle exception
  return null;
} finally {
  c.close();
}
return o;
```

Comment: They have different behavior. Which one do you want?

Comment: I think the question would be clearer if it included some code examples.

Comment: in general there is no right place: depending on the code in question, it is perfectly correct to return in any and all places.

Comment: Learn how the programming language works, instead of programming by implementing some recipe without understanding what you are doing.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question; it's less ambiguous now and I hope to receive your votes for reopen. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It completely depends on what you are trying to do. See the following code for some examples of the possibilities (not all of which should be combined in any single piece of code!).

```
try {
    // do something that may fail
    return 0; // return a normal value
} catch(SomeException e) {
    // maybe log an error
    return -1 // maybe return a default or error value
} finally {
    // maybe clean up resources
    // finally will be executed even if you return in try or catch
    // a return here will trump a return in try/catch. This is generally regarded as a bad idea
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java
}
return 1 // return a normal value here instead of in the try/catch.
// May be clearer than multiple return statements  
// Also useful if return value does not depend on the try/catch outcome
```

**Update** for your updated question. It's partly a matter of preference, though there are significant reasons for each choice. Many people prefer a *single point of return*, so would do this:

```
Object o = null;
try {
  Connection c = getConnection();
  o = c.getThing();
} catch (Exception e) {
  //handle exception; leave o as null
} finally {
  c.close();
}
return o;
```

Although this sounds like it should be clearer, of course one still has to examine the code to determine what value(s) `o` may end up with, so the advantage isn't great.

However, the other options have the advantage that the returning of `null` is very explicit. This is good if you are one of the many programmers who consider returning `null` values to be generally a bad idea (see Tony Hoare's "[billion dollar mistake](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3186)").

Instead of returning `null` one can use "Optional", "Option" or "Maybe" types (available in e.g. Java 8, Scala, Haskell and the Functional Java library), or use the Null Object pattern.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question; it's less ambiguous now and I hope to receive your votes for reopen. Thank you