# finally block in exception handling

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally, finally

Why in the below code,the value of x is not updating although the finally block executes,

```
public class Student
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        ABC obj=new ABC();
        System.out.println("x : "+obj.display());
    }
}

class ABC
{
    int x;
    int display()
    {
        try
        {
            x=10;
            System.out.print("Inside Try ");
            return x;
        }
        finally
        {
            x=x+20;
            System.out.print("I execute ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this code is

Inside Try
I execute
x : 10

Although the finally block is executing, the value of x is not changing. Can somebody please explain why?

Comment: @Juned Ahsan-I am a beginner in java,and I am unable to understand that post,that involves thread which I haven't read upto now

Comment: Because you `return x` before you modify it the second time.  The value has already been "stored" for return, so any modifications aren't modifying the same value/context

Comment: It isn't a method, it's a block.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Wrong duplicate. It's really a duplicate of [does return trump finally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally).

Comment: @EJP yeah i selected the wrong one but couldn't revert it.