# Finally with callback listeners

Tags: java, android, try-catch

So, I have the following code:

```
try{
....
    if(serverResp.isSucces()){
      callbackListener.onDataLoaded(serverResp);
    }

 }catch(Exception e){
 //...do whatever I have to
}finally{
  urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

My question is, when the urlConnection.disconnect is being called? Most of the examples with finally explains when its called in case of **return**. I understand that case, but here I don't have return but to call to a listener.
In most cases the listener callback triggers a new Activity to start. I would like to be sure, that all my previous connections are closed down!

So the main question is:

- When the finally get's called, if there is no return but listener callback?
- Is this a proper way to close the urlConnection?

Comment: No, this explains with return

Comment: I think it would be easy to do some tests see if it's being called.

Comment: Finally is called in 1) normal execution without error, 2) Error in try block 3) Error in catch block as well

Comment: ok, but what if the listener start a loop which goes for 10 mins. Are the finally executed after that 10 mins or before?

Answer (score 0):

`finally` is the best place to close resources.

The `finally` block is executed after the point in which the `try`/`catch` blocks are exited. This occurs when:

1. The end of the `try` block is reached
2. The `try` block is exited in any other way (`break` out of an outer loop, `return`, an uncaught exception is thrown, etc.)
3. An exception is caught and execution reaches the end of the `catch` block
4. The thread executing this code is terminated.

The only times that `finally` may not be executed are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java).

In your case, supposing no exceptions are thrown, your callback will be executed before the connection is closed. The connection will be closed after the callback is complete (via full execution or delegatation to some other thread).

Note that `disconnect` may only be a safe way to ensure connections are closed in newer version of Java. You would normally attempt to read the entire response and then close the input stream. You can find numerous discussions about this on this site.