# how to terminate finally block and execute rest of the code outside the try...catch...finally block

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        System.out.println("This is try block...!!");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception is "+e);
    }
    finally
    {
        System.exit(0);//terminates finally block
        System.out.println("This is finally block");
    }
    System.out.println("This is outside the try catch block...");
}
```

In above code i got output like this "**This is try block...!!**"

But i want output such that,
"**This is try block...!!**"
"**This is outside the try catch block...!!**"

can any one give me correct solution for this problem? and how can i get output as i want?does any one explain me please?

Comment: If you don't want the JVM to exit, don't call System.exit(). It's that simple.

Comment: you exit the program in `finally` block. `finally` block will always be called, no matter what happens

Comment: Who told you that "`System.exit(0);` terminates finally block"?

Comment: If you don't want the logic of the finally block to execute, why do you have a finally block?

Comment: *"can any one give me (...) solution for this problem"* What problem?

Comment: Finally block is always execute no matter if it occur exception or not. So if you executing code     System.exit(0); it terminates. So it doesn't go and print the code after finally block.

Comment: As mentioned, the finally block will always execute right after the end of scope for the `try` or `catch`. `System.exit(0)` will always exit the program, so your code forces an exit of the program before it hits the last line. You do not need the `System.exit(0);` line. But the biggest issue is that you didn't do much to help yourself here.  I have some advice in my next comment......

Comment: [Please, do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) then **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).

Answer (score 1):

it's only for your situation if you want to skip execution of finally block when try is success.

```
boolean trySuccessflag = false;
         try{
            System.out.println("This is try block...!!");
             trySuccessflag = true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception is "+e);
        }
        finally
        {

            if(!trySuccessflag){            
                System.out.println("This is finally block");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("This is outside the try catch block...");
```

Answer (score 0):

*Your question has already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java/65049#65049)*

**Your problem :**

First you have to know that `finally` block is always executed, either you succeed or fail the try block.

Second, `System.exit(0)` exit the System. So the JVM. Not the Try block. So when you call your program simply terminates that's why nothing more is printed.

**Solution :**

First if you don't want to execute the Finally block, just do not write it. It makes no sense to write a code you don't want to execute.

Second, if you really need to exit the finally block use `break;` instead of `System.exit(0);`

Comment: i also think like that there is no meaning to put finally block if i want to terminate it but i face this problem in interview question and i gave same answer but she said me for search about it and make me wrong....but however thanks for give me reply

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be so...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try{
    System.out.println("This is try block...!!");
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception is "+e);
}
System.out.println ("This is outside the try catch block...");
```

}

Your "System.exit(0);" is before your "System.out.println ("This is outside the try catch block...")". So It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this instruction :

System.exit(0);//terminates finally block

It stop the application not terminate the finally block