# Is finally block is really needed?

Tags: java, try-catch, finally

If the statements after the catch block is going to be executed anyway what is the real use of finally block in java?
Example

```
 try {
 //Code
}
catch (Exception e)
{
//Code
}
finally {
 System.out.println("anyway it will be        executed");
 }

System.out.println("anyway it will be executed");
```

Comment: Anywhere in the code there may be a return statement.  Even though the code may have returned to the calling method, the code in the `finally` block will **still** be executed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement at the bottom is not guaranteed to be executed. For example, if

- the `try` block or a matched `catch` block use `return` (or `break` in some circumstances)
- none of the `catch` blocks match the exception, and the exception is thus uncaught
- another (or same) exception is raised (and not caught) inside `catch`

In all of these cases, `finally` statements *are* guaranteed to be executed.

Comment: and even if we add `System.exit(0)` in try block

Comment: @AshishKudale: I haven't tried, but not according to [Does finally always execute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java). In Python, `finally` is executed even on `exit`, but Java doesn't seem to offer the same courtesy.

Comment: Adding to the answer. The primary use of finally is to release resources that were locked inside the try block. For example: Suppose you have a file opened in try. You can write several catch blocks handling multiple exception types. And its not wise to close the opened file in each catch block(Redundancy). And so Finally helps you here by having the close file logic written only in one place.

Comment: @AshishKudale No finally block will not be executed after System.exit(0) and your program will be terminated immediately after executing System.exit(0)..

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh: Getting further off-topic now, but no, not _quite_ immediately - there's still (barely) time for shutdown hooks (see [`Runtime.addShutdownHook`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) ).

Comment: Thanks @Amadan. I was not aware of that :)

Answer (score 1):

Your catch can `return` or throw an exception, and before that happens you can use finally to release resources for example. Finally executes before the control is passed back to the caller.