# Breakpoint in `finally` not being hit

Tags: java, breakpoints

I was messing around with some `try...catch...finally` executions and noticed a breakpoint in `finally` won't seem to be hit:

```
    try {
        System.out.println("in try");
        int num = 5 / 0;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("in catch");
    } finally {
        System.out.println(); //breakpoint here
        System.out.println("in finally");
    }
```

The breakpoint in the `finally` doesn't seem to hit, however it prints out successfully.

However, if I change the `try` to `int num = 5 / 1;`, and therefore not going in to the `catch`, the breakpoint **is** hit.

I'm using Netbeans 8.1.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Are you in debug mode?

Comment: @NiVeR I can hit a breakpoint in the `try` for example.

Comment: @Shark `System.out.println();` doesn't print nothing. It prints a newline.

Comment: @Shark no it won’t hit the line after, I added the two lines to test both just in case.

Comment: if  clean/refresh will not help you can decompile the code to see what is going on

Comment: may be issue with env/IDE, I'm able to do the same on my env.

Comment: `exampleMethod()` and `exampleMethod2()` invoke each other infinitely. Are you sure neither of these methods is being called anywhere? Can you for testing remove the call to `exampleMethod2()` withing exampleMethod and see if finally is still not reached?

Comment: @Hulk it’s Netbeans but I’ll try eclipse and/or IntelliJ shortly when I get a chance.

Comment: @Hulk *Does it get hit if there is no exception?* - good point - and yes it does hit so I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

is happening because in catch you are infinitely looping throw functions if you see your code

exampleMethod() is calling exampleMethod2() and exampleMethod2() calling exampleMethod() so you have a loop with function thats why you get StackoverFlowError

try to functions not call itself

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    try {
        System.out.println("in try");
        int num = 5 / 0;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("in catch");
        exampleMethod();
    } finally {
        System.out.println(); // <--- breakpoint here
        System.out.println("in finally");
    }
}

static void exampleMethod() {

}
```

in this example brakepoint hit in finally

Comment: If you see the end of the post - the same problem is present without any call to the example methods.

Comment: OP knows that. `finally` will still be executed (after the `StackOverflowError` is thrown).

Comment: @achAmháin the method could be invoked from somewhere else?

Comment: @achAmháin maybe you have some problems with editor because i tried and it hit the brake-point

Comment: I will try with other IDEs when I’m back on my machine shortly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-a-finally-block-always-get-executed-in-java) finally is skipped because the infinite recursion (also this question might be a duplicate of that)

Or if not i think you should recompile the whole project. So even if you delete that function call, maybe the compiled classes still have that infinite recursion.

**EDIT**

Here is the proof that it works. So please try to recompile it, delete caches, etc, or please give us a bit more description about the exact problem.

[image]

Comment: As I commented below the other answer, I tried without the exception and the same result applies.

Comment: There is no infinite loop. There is "infinfite recursion", but this is actually quite finite (due to stack overflow)

Comment: Edited my answer, and yes @Hulk you are right, that is an infinite recursion, not loop, thanks for pointing that out :)