# What happens to exception raised by inner catch block

Tags: java, exception

When I run the following java code, I get the output as "ACDF". Could someone please explain how the runtime exception thrown in innermost catch block is handled? (I was expecting it to be handled in the block where "E" is being appended to result string variable)

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static String someFunction() {
        String result = "";
        String str = null;

        try {
            try {
                try {
                    result += "A";
                    str.length();
                    result += "B";
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    result += "C";
                    throw new RuntimeException(); // where this one goes????

                } finally {
                    result += "D";
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                result += "E";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result += "F";
        }


        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(someFunction());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`finally` is ***always*** executed (ignoring special edge cases where the whole JVM dies). I am not kidding, even if you `return`, it will be executed before the `return`.

See [Does a finally block always get executed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-a-finally-block-always-get-executed-in-java) for details.

So when you throw `RuntimeException`, you will first execute the `finally` that appends `D`.

Since you throw `Exception` there, you will run into the `catch (Exception e)` block now, as `catch (RuntimeException e)` does not match. Hence, you append `F`.

Thus, the result is `ACDF`.

---

Annotated code:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static String someFunction() {
        String result = "";
        String str = null;

        try {
            try {
                try {
                    result += "A";
                    str.length(); // throws NullPointerException
                    result += "B";
                } catch (NullPointerException e) { // continue here
                    result += "C";
                    throw new RuntimeException();

                } finally { // finally is always executed
                    result += "D";
                    throw new Exception(); // throwing this
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) { // does not match
                result += "E";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { // matches, continue here
            result += "F";
        } // cool, all done


        return result; // returning ACDF
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(someFunction());
    }
}
```