# Type mismatch using Jedis in Scala

Tags: scala, redis, lift, jedis

The following code produces four type mismatch errors.  Why?  In the first and second cases I'm doing a simple comparison with Strings.  In the third case I'm assigning `false` to a var of type `Boolean`.  In the final case I'm merely printing a stack trace!

I am befuddled.

The code:

```
//return TRUE if logged in
def isLoggedIn(auth: String): Boolean = {
    val jedis = pool.getResource()
    var userid = jedis.get("auth:" + auth)
    var retVal = false
    try {
        if(userid != null) { //error here
            val userAuth = jedis.get("uid:" + userid + ":auth")
            if(userAuth == auth) { // error here
                retVal = true // error here
            }
        }
    } catch {
        case e => e.printStackTrace() //error here
    } finally {
        pool.returnResource(jedis)
        return retVal
    }
}
```

The error:

```
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]                     retVal = true // error here
[error]                            ^
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]                 if(userAuth == auth) { // error here
[error]                 ^
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]             if(userid != null) { //error here
[error]             ^
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]             case e => e.printStackTrace() //error here
[error]                                        ^
[error] four errors found
```

I'm using Jedis 2.0.0 (https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) to interface with a Redis DB.  the Jedis.get() method returns `String`.  I'm using sbt 0.10.1 and scala 2.9.0-1.

What's going on?

Comment: We'd need more context to be able to help you figure out what's going on.  For example, what's the surrounding method or expression supposed to return?  What line/column is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: Sorry.  I added more code and details on the error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.  Needed to move the `return` out of the try/catch/finally.  Here's the updated code, which compiles just fine.  My lingering question is: why can't the `return` be in the finally?

```
//return TRUE if logged in
def isLoggedIn(auth: String): Boolean = {
    val jedis = pool.getResource()
    var userid = jedis.get("auth:" + auth)
    var retVal = false
    try {
        if(userid != null) { 
            val userAuth = jedis.get("uid:" + userid + ":auth")
            if(userAuth == auth) { 
                retVal = true 
            }
        }
    } catch {
        case e => e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        pool.returnResource(jedis)
    }
    return retVal
}
```

Comment: That won't answer your question but here are some thoughts on why you should not use a `return` statement in a `finally` block. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java By the way you can omit the `return` keyword in Scala.