# Java: handle exception and return result from inner method

Tags: java

**Question:** *How to do both: handle exception in `outer` method and return result of `inner` method?*

**I have:** two methods which return `List`:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Result = " + new HelloWorld().parseWrapper()); 
     }

     public List<Integer> inner() {
         List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             if (i % 4 == 0) throw new RuntimeException();
             list.add(i);
         }
         return list;
     }

     public List<Integer> outer() {
         List<Integer> list = null;
         try {
             list = parse();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Handle exception!");
         } finally {
             return list;
         }
     }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Handle exception!
Result = null // PROBLEM: I DON'T WANT TO LOOSE IT
```

**Problem:** I loose result list. I want both: to handle exception and to return [1, 2, 3] list from `outer` method.

Comment: Create a `Result` object hat has a `list` and an `exception`. Return that.

Comment: `new HelloWorld().parseWrapper()` and `parse()` in method `outer` are both syntax errors. Should we assume that `outer` and `inner` were originally called `parseWrapper` and `parse`?

Comment: BTW, returning from a `finally` block is generally considered a bad thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java

Comment: Also, the list would be empty, it wouldn't contain [1, 2, 3], since the exception would be thrown on the first iteration of the loop, before anything had been added to the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - the inner method doesn't return anything, because it throws an exception *instead*. The outer method simply doesn't have a result to work with.

If a method throws an exception, it's generally expected that *none* of the work in the method is useful.

If you want to populate a list as far as you can, you could pass the list *into* the method instead:

```
public void inner(List<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0) throw new RuntimeException();
        list.add(i);
    }
}
```

Then call it as:

```
public List<Integer> outer() {
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>;
    try {
        parse(list);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Handle exception!");
    } finally {
        return list;
    }
}
```

It's rarely a good idea, to be honest - in my experience, most exceptions can't really be handled and resumed; it's more a case of "work out what needs to be cleaned up, and the unit of work to abort". That's not universally true of course, but what you're trying to achieve in terms of *partial* results from a method is pretty rarely useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could just bring your list instanciation at the class level:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public List<Integer> inner() {         
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         if (i % 4 == 0) throw new RuntimeException();
         list.add(i);
      }
      return list;
    }

    public List<Integer> outer() {
        try {
            parse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Handle exception!");
        } finally {
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Just be careful with multiple accesses to the same instance of your class, as you will be messing with same list instance in each call.

But still I'm wondering the real reason of throwing an exception there instead of just returning the partial list:

```
if (i % 4 == 0) return list;
```