# Why compiler doesn't tell about compile time exception?

Tags: java

Can any one help me, what will happen when i will execute this program.

It should throw compile time error, but its not giving it.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int c = getCount();
    System.out.println(c);
}

private static int getCount() {
    try{
        throw new IOException();
    }finally{
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: 'It should throw compile time exception'. Why?

Comment: My qustion was 'Why?', your answer is 'Yes'. I am confused.

Comment: What is a "compile time exception". Do you mean a "compile time error"?

Comment: Why should it throw a 'compile time exception' (what is that?) when you try to throw an `IOException`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning from a finally block in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java)

Answer (score 10):

It's because you have a `return` statement in your `finally` block - so the `IOException` is not actually going to be thrown out of your `getCount()` method. If a `finally` block completes abruptly (i.e. it throws an exception or has a return statement), that is the way that the whole try/finally or try/catch/finally block completes.

From [JLS section 14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2):

> If execution of the try block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V, then there is a choice:
>
> - ...
> - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and the throw of value V is discarded and forgotten).

And from [section 11.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2) (exception analysis of statements) - emphasis is mine:

> A try statement (§14.20) can throw an exception class E iff either:
>
> - The try block can throw E, or an expression used to initialize a resource (in a try-with-resources statement) can throw E, or the automatic invocation of the close() method of a resource (in a try-with-resources statement) can throw E, and E is not assignment compatible with any catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement, and **either no finally block is present or the finally block can complete normally**
> - ...

In your case, the finally block *cannot* complete normally (i.e. get to the closing brace) due to the return statement, so the result of the analysis of the try statement is that it cannot throw the exception.

If you move the `return 10;` to after the `finally` block, you'll get the error you expected.