# Java: Incompatible types: ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm getting an error that states an ArrayList cannot be converted to int
on my `return arr`

I'm writing a program in which I have to read all ints from a file and calculate their sum.  I'm also handling all exceptions, so if an exception is thrown, the function should return 0.

Here is my code:

```
 public static int intFileSum(String fileName) 
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        InputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Scanner s=new Scanner(fis);
        try {
            while (s.hasNextInt()) {
                arr.add(s.nextInt());
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return 0;
        } catch (IOException f) {
            return 0;
        } finally {
            fis.close();
            s.close();
            return arr;
        }
    }
```

Here is my unit test that should pass once the file is read:

```
public void testSumIntsHappyPath() throws Exception
    {       
        int sum=Assignment11.intFileSum("inputs/ints1.txt");
        Assert.assertEquals(10, sum);

        sum=Assignment11.intFileSum("inputs/ints2.txt");
        Assert.assertEquals(56, sum);   
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `public static int intFileSum` can not `return arr`... Change the return type

Comment: An `ArrayList<Integer>` cannot be converted to an integer! Look at your return value and return type, and read the error message!

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to intFileSum (which would essentially mean that the method is calling itself.) It is now saying cannot find symbol

Comment: No, you *need* a return type. `int` is correct, the ArrayList is just wrong

Comment: [Never ever return from a finally block!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/48088/3888450)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an Arraylist?

You want to sum the numbers, so do that.

```
 public static int intFileSum(String fileName) {
    int sum = 0;
    InputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fileName);
    Scanner s=new Scanner(fis);
    try {
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            sum += s.nextInt();
```

And then, `return sum`

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList.add()` doesnt do sum operation. It adds element to a list.

Ref : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)

Use following code :

`result = result + s.nextInt()`

Instead of :
`arr.add(s.nextInt());`

Declare `int result` outside of the loop and return `result` instead of `arr`

Answer (score 0):

So far all you have done is read all the data from the file and put it into an array (the add method adds an element to an array, it does not compute any sum). Then you try to return the arr array, but the method return type is int, which is causing the error.

Instead try something like this (I don't think you even need the array unless you plan to use it for something else later):

```
int TOTAL = 0;
while (s.hasNextInt()) {
    TOTAL += s.nextInt();
}
```

then instead of "return arr;" you want to:

```
return TOTAL;
```

Note: you might have to add some checks for valid input as well.

Comment: I was going to delete this as I saw others had responded while I was writing with same answer, but based on his/her reply to comments, I think the requester may benefit from the explanation at the beginning of why its erroring out so I'll leave it.