# Quit Java Class Extended to Thread class on Exception

Tags: java, android

I am using simple java class extended to Thread for doing background network or other data operations. I want to quit the code in case exception occurs. Presently the code do not stop whether exception occurs or not. I tired using `return;` and `.interrupt();` by making object of class but none of them helped me in stopping the code.

My class structure as below:

```
public class sample extends Thread{
Context mcontext;
public sample(Context context){
this.mcontext = context;
}
@override
public void run(){
scan(mcontext);
}

public void scan(){

try{
//Code to execute
}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace}
//What to do to exit code here reaching first time
}
}
```

Comment: You're not invoking `scan()` there, you're invoking some other overload which takes a parameter. Does that overload have try/catch in it too? (Well, actually, this code doesn't compile, so who knows what you're actually doing).

Comment: I m calling this as new sample(getContext).start;

Comment: Try return statement in finally block

Comment: it worked with return in finally block. Thanks.

Comment: @NitinDhomse no, don't return from a finally block. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java

Comment: u means I do like this finally {
       
        return rtn;
    } How can I return some object when method is void.