# java vm specification abrupt completion of a method

Tags: java

The Java VM specification has the following statement under the topic of Abrupt Method Invocation Completion.

" A method invocation that completes abruptly never returns a value to its invoker."

How is then the finally block in this piece of code able to return a value?

```
public class WaitTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j = methodThatExitsAbruptly(0);
        System.out.println(j);
    }

    public static int methodThatExitsAbruptly(int i) {
        try {
            if (i == 0) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            return 1;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Never** ever return within a `finally` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is not considered to complete normally<sup>1</sup>. That is because a value is returned in the `finally` block, **discarding any thrown exception**.

[JLS § 14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) contains more info about the order of execution.

Remember to **never** ever return a value from the `finally` block. The reason that this was made possible was perhaps a design error within the Java language, and the reason it is still possible is possibly for backward-compatibility reasons.

See also:

- [Returning from a finally block in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java)
- [Don't return in a finally clause](https://web.archive.org/web/20070922061412/http://weblogs.java.net/blog/staufferjames/archive/2007/06/_dont_return_in.html)

PS: You can configure most IDE's to warn you about returning a value in the `finally` block.

---

<sup>1</sup> JLS § 14.20.2 says:

> If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason R.

but a `return` is [considered an abrupt completion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1).

Answer (score 0):

Docs just feel contradicting each other (see actual answer below the horizontal line).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html has what you are asking about:

> 2.6.5. Abrupt Method Invocation Completion
>
> [...] A method invocation that completes abruptly never returns a value to its invoker.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html speaks about completion of statements and blocks:

> 14.1. Normal and Abrupt Completion of Statements
>
> [...]
>   An abrupt completion always has an associated reason, which is one of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - A return with no value
> - A return with a given value

This also applies to blocks (14.2).

Then https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html says

> 8.4.7. Method Body
>
> A method body is either a block of code that implements the method or simply a semicolon, indicating the lack of an implementation.
>
> [...] If a method is declared to have a return type, then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).

TL;DR: abrupt completion does not provide a return value, return always completes (itself, the block and the method body) abruptly.

---

However what applies to your case is exactly one line below than what @MCEmperor [quoted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2):

> If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason R.
>
> **If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).**

(I have not even added the formatting, it is bold already on the page)