# Getting Error :: The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a sample lib using which client can execute their code, to achieve it I am using a functional programming feature of JAVA.
But getting compilation error  **The target type of this expression must be a functional interface**

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ImplemenetIt<T> {
    public T provideYourImpl();
}

public class HighOrderFunctionClass<T> {

    public T executeCode(ImplemenetIt<T> it, T defaultAnswer) {
        T answer = defaultAnswer;

        return () -> { // At this line I am getting error
            try {
                answer = it.provideYourImpl();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            } finally {
                return answer;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Please, suggest what I am missing.

Comment: The body of your lambda expression is totally harmful. You are catching all `Exception`s, but then silently ignore them (for your `catch` block is empty). The exceptions would be swallowed anyway, because you have a `return` inside your `finally` block. You [shouldn't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48740/507738).

Comment: Regarding the error you're getting: you define the return type of `executeCode` to be a `T`, but you're trying to return some implementation of a functional interface. However, `T` can be any type, so the lambda expression cannot conform to `T`.

Answer (score 1):

A [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) is the implementation of a functional interface. Your method `executeCode()` returns a generic type (`T`) and `T` is not a functional interface but the code in method `executeCode()` is trying to return a functional interface.

Also one of the parameters to method `executeCode()` is a functional interface, so when you call that method, you can pass a lambda expression as an argument, i.e.

```java
executeCode( () -> return null, someDefault )
```

Here is a more "concrete" example.

```java
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HighOrderFunctionClass<String> hofc = new HighOrderFunctionClass<>();
        String someDefault = "I am the default value.";
        ImplemenetIt<String> it = () -> return "Hello world.";
        String result = hofc.executeCode(it, someDefault);
    }
}
```